# Why was my edit rejected for changing the intent, when the op stated it doesn't

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194121/classes-in-same-package) the OP asks for a problem with IntelliJ Idea not seeing a type, however he provided an invalid example:

```
public class A { ... some stuff here ...}

public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A myVar = 1234;
    }
}
```

On a later line he then says the example doesn't work bat the problem isn't the 1234 but that IntelliJ doesn't see A. I then suggested a change of `1234` to `new A()` to make the example correct.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5704053

However it was rejected for changing the intent, however I think it instead made the question follow the intent more as OP also says in a comment to [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10194378/1648883).

It seems that this is a [common issue on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254840/1648883) (also read the question to that answer).

Some suggestions I've found on the meta include:

- **Re-post the edit**. This just feels wrong.
- **Post a comment**. I don't want to do this, since the question is over 2 years old, and the OP has even stated this in his own comments.

What can I do in this situation? Do you think it should have been rejected?

**EDIT**: I posted this question hoping I would get information on how to improve my edits. All I got is *If the OP thinks the edit is correct, he should post it himself.* This however makes me ask, why is the edit system in place? It's clearly not used as is described:

> **How to Edit**
>
> - fix grammatical or spelling errors
> - clarify meaning without changing it
> - correct minor mistakes
> - add related resources or links
> - always respect the original author

If the OP said the code doesn't really matter, why is correcting it incorrect? I feel like the edit system is thought of as "change unreadable formatting into readable" and not "improve answer/question". I clearly did what is described in point 2 - clarify meaning. I changed the code according to his OWN comments.

Also, I'm curious why are so many people down-voting this question (not angry, just curious). Are you seriously reading the whole question with comments or just down-voting because it's related to edits? Could every down-voter at least leave a comment?

**EDIT2**: Noticed a [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267845/1648883) in Related. I feel like my question is very similar to that one but it's taken much more negatively, anyone care to explain?

Comment: Changing code in a question can be dangerous because it could very well be the problem. This makes them more likely to be rejected even if they are correct.

Comment: @codeMagic The OP stated this is not the problem in his comment on the question and the answer.

Comment: I understand that. The OP should have changed it himself if he wanted an answer. To post invalid syntax is silly. Anyway, did you mention in your edit suggestion all of this? If you don't leave a clear explanation of *why* you are changing code in a post then there is a good chance it will get rejected. If you **do** explain then the reviewers are more likely to take a deeper look

Comment: @Nulano No, actually, he didn't.  In fact, he [specifically said he couldn't do what you changed his code to do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194121/classes-in-same-package#comment13087655_10194378).

Comment: @Servy That's true but that's where the problem seems to be

Comment: @Servy He asked for help with IntelliJ Idea not seeing A, not help with Java syntax. See his comment on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10194378/1648883

Answer (score 10):

If the OP agrees with your edit, he can approve the edit unilaterally.

The reason why your edit got rejected is because the OP didn't do that.

Comment: The OP probably didn't do that, because he didn't even get a chance to do it, it was rejected in less than 20 minutes. Or are you saying he will still be notified and can do this, and un-reject the edit?

Comment: @Nulano 20 minutes isn't that short of a time

Comment: For people that aren't that active on SO (such as me and the OP) it's a very short time. I usually only go to SO only through Google searches and it would probably take me a month to find out someone edited my question.

Comment: @Nulano Normally, when someone asks a question, we expect them to come back and check up on it, if for no other reason than to see if there are any answers.   Most people don't wait until they stumble upon their own question again in a search.

Comment: The question is already 2 years old. I wouldn't expect anyone to check it in the exact half-hour when my edit was being reviewed.