# Is it OK to edit the question to change the author's intention?

Tags: discussion, edits

I am talking about the following question:

*[Why is a `fork()` call not optimized away in an infinite loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295427/why-is-a-fork-call-not-optimized-away-in-an-infinite-loop)*

The author asked a low-quality question which was definitely not a quality-add to the site. A high-reputed user then edited the question to make it a really interesting question, which most possibly was not what user wanted to ask, but would be useful for a lot of readers.

What is the intended action for such questions?

1. Edit them, even to the extent that new question is different from the author's question.
2. Ignore the question and let it to get deleted and ask the edited question in parallel as a new question.

Comment: A fork-bomb, *sigh*.  Hard to see why anybody would care.  But it got rolled-back and that invalidated your answer.  I think the proper advice is to just not waste your time on crap questions.

Comment: Is the current question a good one? Are fake internet points things people should avoid being concerned about? Where all answers present still correct after the edit to the closed question? --- If the answer to these three questions is 'yes', then what is the issue?

Comment: I voted to close this question. My opinion is that unless a question containing obviously malicious code comes with a clear statement warning readers that it's dangerous then it should be closed or deleted. In spite of all the attempts to polish this turd of a question, none of the subsequent edits bothered to point out this very basic thing to any naive users who happened to chance upon it, therefore they should have been deleted with just as much prejudice as the original question.

Comment: If only the OP were here to clarify matters. A lot of things can happen (and have) in six hours - there is still a chance the question may be undeleted in the meantime, even if it's deleted now.

Comment: @GrantWinney, I'll repeat what I commented on my answer: _"If the OP confirms the original intentions of the post were incorrect, the **OP** should edit the question. Not some random passer-by."_ Only the OP really knows what he's trying to ask, and what aspects of a problem he needs help with.

Comment: Maybe not quite as random, but I'm still convinced the OP asked exactly what he wanted to ask. (He even stated that's what the teacher asked him). Changing the intent of a question shouldn't be done by anyone but the OP, imo.

Comment: By the way, the close reason headlines as "unclear what you're asking", and the description is consistently written in the second person. No prizes for guessing who "you're" refers to.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To answer your main question: *"Is it OK to edit the question to change the author's intention?"*

### Absolutely not.

**Completely** changing the *intentions* of the question is hardly ever a good idea.

---

Your linked example used to be a *"What does code X do?"* question, but the edit changed it to *"Is the compiler allowed to optimize away the following loop?"* , Which, in my opinion, appears to be different.

As [@apsillers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/710446/apsillers) [answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288827/1835379), the edit forced the unclear question into one of multiple possible interpretations of the question. If the editor guessed right, that's great. If he didn't, the edit possibly made the post confusing to the OP, resulting in the OP possibly being unable to accept the right answer.

Comment: For the reasons I mentioned in this answer, I've reverted the related edit, and close-voted the question. At time of writing, the question is at `-11` already. That's hardly salvage-able.

Comment: If the OP confirms the original intentions of the post were incorrect, the ___OP___ should edit the question. Not some random passer-by. I'd appreciate it if you'd stop calling me an ignorant vandal. That's _not_ constructive at all.

Comment: I repeat: _"the **OP** should edit the question."_

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I think you edited the question into a fundamentally different question. The level of pre-existing understanding demonstrated by a question affects what is being asked in the question. You substantially altered that level of understanding with your edit. The question you edited it into seems like a good question -- feel free to ask that question as your own! It *should* be a different question, because how one ought to answer the OP's question and how to answer your new question seem quite different.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf (Last thing, I promise:) While the OP did say that the question was asked in an academic context, it's not clear what kind of academic context. It could be that the course requires no C/C++ knowledge at all, and the professor was looking for an answer about what would happen to the system's processor(s), scheduling, RAM usage, `proc` files, etc. The question posed was "What does this code do?" and you changed it to the different question "Should this loop get removed by the compiler?" without clear indication from the OP whether that was actually the question being asked.

Comment: From my perspective, the person who edited the question did not change the intent of the question. If anything, they greatly clarified it. Unless you have reason to believe otherwise (the OP saying as much), it's better not to assume and not look a gift horse in the mouth.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: The question was nothing more than _"What does this code do?"_, and was changed to _"Is the compiler allowed to optimize away the following loop?"_ The OP was in _no_ way involved in this edit (Looking at the comments at the time of the edit). I really don't see how the intent _wasn't_ changed there.

Comment: The outcome of the code is trivial to determine if the compiler is not allowed to optimize away the loop. I have to admit that after your bolded **completely** I was expecting to read "... but this edit doesn't **completely** change the question."

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Not being accusatory here, just want to understand your position and reasoning.  How can we assume that the edit made anything more clear?  If we are unsure of the author's original intent, we can't with any certainty say we communicated that unknown any better.  One of the suggested edit queue reject reason is "**clearly conflicts with author's intent** This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner. "

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Also, why should we assume an edit is "innocent until proven guilty" or good until proven bad?  Usually when someone writes an unclear question, we put the onus on the author to clarify and write a better question or have their post closed.  Wouldn't the fact that we close unclear questions and make the author's fix them before reopening suggest that it is not our job to divine someone's intent but to make them do it because we can not?

Comment: @Becuzz See [Shog9's answer for why we should always strive to help where we can:](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/16587)

Comment: Really bummed to see this answer accepted. Cerbrus, you started an edit war on someone else's question and defended it with dogma; even if the edit you rolled back (repeatedly) *was* incorrect, your behavior in response to it was, frankly, shameful. In the future, please try to solve such disputes with [simple, *polite*, communication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/).

Comment: @Shog9 - I don't think it's "dogma" to point out that it's not a good idea (though I think '_disrespectful_' is a better description) to put words in someone else's mouth _without getting their assent, *first*_.  The guidelines that you cite _in your own answer_ clearly indicate that _it is not appropriate to change the meaning of a post_ or to do things that could be construed as disrespectful.  Unilaterally rewriting someone's post, when you could just as easily ask them first and get confirmation, is disrespectful and arrogant.

Comment: Respect is not a destination, @aroth, but a starting point one sets out from. You are not a machine, forced to translate without understanding: you should strive to *understand* the meaning of the post you're editing, **out of respect**; you should strive to *convey* that meaning with your edit, **out of respect**. If you *can't* understand what you're reading, then there's a limit to what you can accomplish with an edit but no shame in trying; if you *won't* understand what you're reading, or allow its meaning to influence how you edit, then you are not starting from respect.

Comment: (More than) A bit late, but my opinion on this is that the edited version itself is good... **but** the fact that there was no apparent communication with the question's OP before the edit, to guarantee that it is in fact the correct interpretation, is a major issue.  While it's extremely likely to at least answer some of the OP's original question, it may come from a higher level of understanding than the OP has, and thus omit information that they might need to be able to properly understand the answers.  I would have rejected the edit on those grounds, and suggested involving the OP first.

Comment: @JustinTime-ReinstateMonica well, the OP would have been scared out of their mind to participate on the conversation once it came down to it. Also, remember, OP is notified of any significant edit to their posts, so they are made aware of it. What else are you expecting us to do? [Waiting 8 years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-data/25336738#comment39511966_25336738)?

Answer (score 39):

The amount of blind dogma being repeated in this thread is depressing... **NO** it's not appropriate to change a question such that it no longer reflects what the asker needed help with - but in order to edit effectively without doing that, **you must first understand the intent of the author!**

How? **Communicate with the author!** And guess what... *Editing is a form of communication!*

The relevant guidelines here - the ones spelled out *[on the full editing page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/288802/edit)* - are simple:

> - clarify meaning without changing it
> - *always* respect the original author

Crucially, there's *nothing* about intent there; you won't always *know* what the intentions of the author were until he clarifies by commenting, accepting or reverting your edit. Arguing about this with other editors is pointless - you might *all* be wrong about what the asker wanted! Unclear questions need edits more than any others, yet the meaning of these posts is hard to understand *by definition;* trying to gauge the author's *intentions* without feedback from the author himself is even more of a minefield. All you can do is treat the asker with respect and do your best to be helpful with your edits.

Now, ask yourself, which is more helpful to the asker: an edit that clarifies a likely question which *makes sense and can be answered?* Or... deletion? Which of these is more helpful to future readers?

Who was helped by the actions taken on *this* post?

### Feynman and the slothful servant

I addressed this [same question on Physics' meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6543/radically-editing-closed-questions/6545#6545) a while back; perhaps my answer there will be helpful here also:

> There's [a famous interview with Richard Feynman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMFPe-DwULM), where he was
>   asked the question, "how do two magnets attract or repel each other?"
>   To which he responded,
>
> > I can't explain that attraction in terms of anything else that's familiar to you.
>
> ...and then went on to list how he might answer the question *if
>   someone else were asking it.* This is a brilliant response, precisely
>   because it illustrates a consideration that so many educators skip:
>   **understanding the intentions of your student.**
>
> The basic guidelines for editing are listed on [the full edit
>   page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/1/edit):
>
> [image: always respect the original author]
>
> Note that they say *nothing* about the "intended" meaning of the post;
>   you're expected to clarify the meaning, which you can hopefully learn
>   by reading the post... but the only way to know if you've preserved
>   the asker's *intent* is to make the edit and see if he's satisfied
>   with the results. When in doubt, **talk to the author:** a comment
>   paired with the edit expressing *your* intent and requesting feedback
>   on your edit can go a long way toward ensuring that your edits are
>   helpful.
>
> The critical guideline here is ***always* respect the original
>   author:** edit with his best interest in mind, strive to make him look
>   good, **write a question that'll get him the help he needs!**
>
> Watching some editors debate this reminds me of [an old story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_talents_or_minas)...
>
> > He also who had received the one talent came and said, "Lord, I knew you that you are a hard man, reaping where you did not sow, and
> >     gathering where you did not scatter. I was afraid, and went away and
> >     hid your talent in the earth. Behold, you have what is yours."
> >
> > But his master answered him, "You wicked and slothful servant. You knew that I reap where I didn't sow, and gather where I didn't
> >     scatter. You ought therefore to have deposited my money with the
> >     bankers, and at my coming I should have received back my own with
> >     interest. Take away therefore the talent from him, and give it to him
> >     who has the ten talents. For to everyone who has will be given, and he
> >     will have abundance, but from him who doesn't have, even that which he
> >     has will be taken away. Throw out the unprofitable servant into the
> >     outer darkness, where there will be weeping and gnashing of teeth."
> >
> > — Matthew 25:24–30, [World English Bible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_English_Bible)
>
> It's always *safe* to edit a question in a way that does not change
>   the literal meaning; after all, who can criticize you when you haven't
>   *done anything?* But when you *do* understand the intent, and yet, out of an overabundance of caution, do nothing to alter the meaning even
>   if by doing so you could better reflect the author's intention *and
>   potentially provide a way for him to obtain assistance here*, then
>   you're hardly respecting the author; like the cynical servant or a
>   weary teacher who no longer cares if his students can absorb the
>   information he regurgitates, you've wasted an opportunity and
>   squandered the attention of your audience.
>
> When you edit a question, or when you review the edits of others, ask
>   yourself this question: **does this edit make it more likely that the
>   asker will obtain the information he needs?** The answer you give
>   yourself to this question should provide you with a foundation for any
>   discussion that might follow from it.

Comment: Editing is a poor form of communication.  Comments work better.  I could have made this point by editing your post, but that seemed unwise.  And if more than one person was trying to "communicate" different ideas at the same time by capturing their speculative assumptions in edits, all you get is discordant chaos.  Cerberus has the right of it; it's not okay to put words into the OP's mouth just because you feel their words are of low quality.

Comment: I would refrain from doing such radical edits without beforehand having positive feedback from the author in the comments. Especially if the author is new, and likely doesn't know about editing, rollbacks, and how he is supposed to react to them. In this particular instance, the comments have unfortunately been nuked, so we cannot judge anymore what extent of clarification was already done before the edit.

Comment: Define "work", @aroth. Comments will rarely get you yelled at; if self-preservation is your goal, then by all means, stick to comments - or do nothing at all, since that's even safer. If you really want to help someone, and have good reason to believe you know what they're after, then editing is a hell of a lot more *effective*, even if the danger of pushback is greater when you're wrong.

Comment: The comments consisted mostly of folks trying to answer the question, @Bergi. The asker thanked them, and then Alf (the editor) and Cerbrus (the top answer here, who also rolled back Alf's edit) got into a heated argument over who was the vandal. Note that Alf has a gold C++ tag badge while Cerbrus has zero C++ answers on SO, and carefully avoided mentioning his own role in this dispute here on meta...

Comment: Aside: if anyone reading is honestly concerned about new users not understanding how edits (and rollbacks) work here, then *teach them!* Editing is the backbone of Stack Overflow; if folks get so twisted up about new users not understanding it that they refrain from editing, this whole thing is doomed. New users should be helped to learn about how this thing works, not coddled in their ignorance.

Comment: "Alf has a gold C++ tag badge while Cerbrus has zero C++ answers on SO" - Objection, relevance.  Shiny things don't grant preferential treatment.  And I don't think anyone has suggested that people refrain from editing.  Just that they respect the already-established guidelines, which as you note don't permit edits that "change the meaning" of content or disrespect the OP.  Editing is not _effective_ communication.  It's just _expedient_ because it cuts out the other person, which is disrespectful IMO when used to change a person's meaning.  Teaching is great, but edits make a poor classroom.

Comment: Maybe I've just consistently met really dense, inattentive or stubborn users, but personal experience has shown me that most users who write and/or format poorly *do not* learn from edits made by other users on their behalf. Not even those who post large numbers of questions or answers with every last one of them being edited by either the same user(s), or different individuals each time. I guess this is where not caring about the author greatly benefits the community at large, since we have more than enough editors to go around anyway. Do I get dibs on the term "edit vampire"?

Comment: If you don't think an understanding of the topic is immensely important when editing (or closing), @aroth... Then we're likely at an impasse: my argument hinges on editors *understanding* the question they're editing and *interpreting* what the asker wrote. Yes, it may be possible to relay an interpretation in a comment, or in answer for that matter... But in cases where the original question is unclear, this is woefully inefficient (and, as the example used here demonstrates, may well result in your interpretation being deleted). It is a poor teacher who can't demonstrate what they teach.

Comment: You're likely in the same position as me, @BoltClock: too much time staring at the very worst questions from the very worst askers. It makes one cynical; I have to seek out contrasting examples now and then, to remind myself that not every asker is so dense.

Comment: I presume this applies to answers as well, just that in this case, the intention of the author is a bit more obvious: answer the question.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60758/should-i-edit-other-peoples-answers-to-remove-incorrect-content-or-should-i-as/60763#60763 @Braiam

Comment: Unfortunately, by design, [authors are *not notified* of all edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415/271271). Thus, editing is *not*, necessarily, a form of communication, due to the fact that the author may never find out the post has been edited. In addition, what the threshold is for edit notifications is undisclosed. As a result, editing, by itself, does not, necessarily, communicate with the user and you have no way to *know* if the user was notified of the edit. To be sure the author's been informed of the edit, it's necessary to *also* leave a comment on the post you edit.

Comment: The threshold [has been disclosed since these notifications appeared 5 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134906/what-type-of-notifications-do-we-have/135411#comment378020_135411), @Makyen. It's very, very unlikely that you're going to both make a massive "heroic" edit *and* the author isn't going to be notified of it. That said, there's certainly no harm in also commenting - just be sure you don't depend on the comment to explain your edit, since it's entirely possible the edit will be seen first.

Comment: @Shog9, I appreciate the information. However, the information regarding thresholds in the link is demonstrably inaccurate. E.g. I was not notified about [this edit (rev. 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45697887/revisions), which added 23 characters to the body and 38 char. to a link (plus 6 changed char.). It says it's a "diff" algorithm, but the version prior to the edit was 1287 char. and the version after the edit is 1348 char. (diff. of 61 characters). It may not include changes to links (it should), but even then it's still 23 char., which is more than the 10 stated in the comment.

Comment: It strips markup prior to comparing, @Makyen - but that should still be more than enough of a change to trigger a notification. And indeed, [it shows up on your profile in the responses tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3773011/makyen?tab=responses&sort=all&page=6#enable-load-revision-14c7c56c-ca03-4905-8130-034d56df61e2), as it should... But, I don't see it in [your global inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/4657998/makyen?tab=inbox&page=13) for the same time period. I tested this internally and was unable to reproduce, suggesting that this may be a bug with the global inbox archive.

Comment: @Shog9, I appreciate you looking into it. I can't say for sure if I did, or did not, receive a notification at the time. I just don't remember. I found it when looking through, as you surmise, my global inbox vs. last edits on my posts trying to find [additional examples for a different comment](/q/357626#comment521745_357626), based on another user and I not being notified for some [erroneous Documentation edits](//chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/39499812#39499812), which primarily changed markup (links). Thus, a bug in the global inbox would account for what I'm sure I observed.

Comment: @Shog9, However, while I understand the choice to not consider markup, I disagree that changes in link targets should be ignored. Changes in the target of links used in a post can be a quite significant change to the post (e.g. material used as reference, etc). This is particularly true if the edit changes the target domain, adds/removes a link, etc.

Comment: I tend to agree, for links at any rate. Might wanna make that a feature-request, @Makyen.

Answer (score 9):

*I no longer fully agree with the answer given below, but I have left it intact for community assessment. I endorse [Shoq9's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836) and point out that the ability to inject authorial intent is compatible with the inviolability of OP edits; the OP can override any edits. The risk of chameleon-question answer invalidation is outweighed by the possibility of improved site quality.*

*Please vote on this answer based on the content below, not the contradictory text above, but feel free to discuss either perspective in a comment.*

---

The problem here is not a change from one intention to another, but a change from an *unclear* intention to a specific intention.

> What is the result when running the following piece of code...
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
>     while ( true )
>         fork();
> }
> ```

The question of "*what is the result?*" can be interpreted in at least three different ways:

- What happens in the other forks generated by this code? (Do they continue looping also? Does this cause exponential or merely linear process growth?)
- What happens to the operating system's and physical system's resources when subjected to this fork bomb? Does (or *how* does) this cause a system failure?
- Can a specification-compliant compiler eliminate the `while` loop as an optimization?

These different questions require *vastly* different answers, and I assert that it's totally unclear in this case which of them is being asked. (If you disagree with me on this assertion, then you believe this question is in a fundamentally different category of clarity than I do, and you will not find my arguments convincing.)

When a question is unclear as this one, it seems detrimental to force it into one of these specific questions without clarification from the OP. Some reasons include:

- If the editor guesses wrong, and the OP returns to assert their original intent, it could invalidate existing answers. The editor would have made a chameleon question, rather than simply an unclear question later clarified by the OP.
- The specificity introduced by the edit may make the question too sophisticated for the OP to understand, leaving them unable to provide clarification (it's not actually their question, so how could they clarify the intent of the new question?) and unable to make an informed decision about which answer to accept, since the question now describes a problem they don't have (or describes it in a way that they cannot understand).

This question should be closed as-is, and the OP should be encouraged to introduce specificity so that it more clearly outlines the problem to be solved. (For example, outline the three possibilities above would have been helpful to the OP here, to highlight just how unclear their question currently is and provide avenues for fixing it.) If the OP provides that clarification, *then* another user could implement that clarification as an edit.

I'd propose that a question needs to have *sufficiently specific authorial intent* (either in the question or comments) in order to be developmentally edited, so that editors do not transform the question into something that is incompatible with what the OP is trying to ask. If it's not clear what the OP is trying to ask, a developmental edit will bind the unclear question into one of many valid, incompatible possibilities. A community-supplied authorial intent seems bad, since it could clash with a later-emerging authorial intent from the OP. (I wish to avoid the situation where some third party is telling the OP what their own question is about: "*Sorry, I already decided your question was about C++ compiler behavior, not about the behavior of the `fork` method. Go ask another question; this one is mine now.*")

Comment: Remember that we are not just writing questions for the OP, but also the next person asking the question who finds it via google. That a given answer helps the OP is incidental to the overall goal of Stack Overflow.

Comment: This answer explains my main problem with the edit: The intent was changed (imo), _without_ the OP's consent or interaction. So, @MichaelT: Should we just completely ignore what the OP's asking (or trying to), in order to write an answer that applies to the literal written question?

Comment: @MichaelT I am certainly sympathetic to the idea that Stack Overflow isn't about getting your question answered but rather building knowledge base, but I still find the notion of overriding the OP's original intent (even if incompletely expressed in the original question) troubling. If the OP comes back to say, "No, I meant option 1," at what point do we say, "Sorry, we incorrectly decided that this question is about option 2 now; go make a new question"? Is it simply a race to see who can edit in plausible specificity first? Is it fixed at the time the first answer is provided?

Comment: @MichaelT After some discussion, the answer to my hypothetical appears to be "never" -- the OP can *always* correctly reassert their original intent and override any specifying edits, even if it causes invalid answers. (I suppose if it's been years without such an assertion, we can safely take the OP long silence for assent and treat the very late reassertion as a chameleon edit.)

Answer (score -6):

Yes it is reasonable to completely overhaul a poor closed question into what could be a good open one, even if it changes the base assumptions of an otherwise unanswered question.

This does several things that are all helpful to the site:

- It shows the OP the expected quality and seriousness of the site.  One particularly effective way of making jokes fall flat is to overanalyze them. This question is no longer 'funny' with the revision.
- Yes, this was *another* fork bomb question. That's boring and poor quality.  The revision makes it into a much more interesting question. That is good content for the site and the [seed for much higher quality answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) than the original provided.

Arguing about who gets the fake internet points is especially boring. They are there to incent quality material on the site.

Once the question is closed, it is fair game for the community to try to make the question into one that can be answered *provided it does not invalidate existing answers*.  This may mean making significant changes to tone and fundamental assumptions in the question.

That this is different than the OP's original intent and question is incidental. The first part of the Q&A site is good **Q**uestions. If someone wants to provide that question by editing a closed question into shape, and in the process help show a user the norms and expectations of Stack Overflow, all the more power to them (`#include <I_wish_I_could_upvote_edits>`).

---

This ***specific*** question about a fork bomb?  Its like asking about recipes that involve mixing lemon juice and baking soda on Cooking.SE and should probably be deleted promptly. The interesting non malicious question could get reasked in a new post.

The ***general*** case of fixing a closed question to be good material even if we aren't the original poster? We don't do that enough.

Comment: I have practical and philosophical concerns about adding editor-supplied specificity to a question when it's absolutely unclear what's being asked: (1) The OP might add their own contradictory clarification, invalidating answers to the externally-edited version. The outside editor causes a chameleon-question situation, when it otherwise would have been an simple unclear-to-clear question transformation. (2) If the question is edited into a more sophisticated one that OP was not prepared to ask, the OP will be ill-equipped to give clarification, understand the answers, and accept one.

Comment: @apsillers if it is absolutely unclear about what is being asked, it probably isn't able to be salvaged.  On the other hand, I consider it the *responsibility* of people who give answers to marginal questions to make a best effort to fix the question even if that means changing the question's intent and direction (and this is likely to get off into tangents). There are too many answers on marginal questions out there today that need to be fixed. Considering the OP's text to be sacrosanct in its message makes fixing those questions harder for the answerer or others.

Comment: You don't ___completely___ rewrite a unsalvageable question in order to "save" it. Downvote, closevote, maybe even comment, move on. Assing information or a sense of understanding to the question does not help the OP in any way. In this case, the person editing it should just have posted a new question, especially since the question was already massively downvoted _and_ closed, at the time the question was edited.

Comment: @MichaelT: _"ven if that means changing the question's intent and direction"_. No. Don't ever change that. Like I commented on my answer here: _"**If** the OP confirms the original intentions of the post were incorrect, the **OP** should edit the question. Not some random passer-by."_

Comment: @Cerbrus the question is where is the unsalvegable threshold. And I certainly agree you shouldn't answer or attempt to fix a question that isn't salvageable. Questions that *do* have answers *should* be fixed (or deleted). The general case, we should be fixing more. Is this question a good one to fix? probably not. There are [160k](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1+closed%3Ayes+score%3A..0+duplicate%3Ano) questions that should be fixed or deleted... and if that means fixing them by changing them, do it.

Comment: In my opinion, when you have to _completely_ rewrite a question, _and_ change it's intentions, you're past "unsalvagable". This question was massively changed at the moment it had (at least) 8 downvotes, was closed, and had _no_ answers at all. The question would've been roomba'd the very next cleanup round.

Comment: @Cerbrus it is *best* and *easiest* to close a question when it has no answers.  This is why poor questions should be closed fast - there are no answers that one has to make sure that the edits don't invalidate. That it was edited *before* there was a question was a good thing.  That ***this*** question was edited at -8... that's another aspect to consider. But editing before answers show up when the question is closed is *exactly* when it should be edited.

Comment: ... I will point out that I have done [*exactly* this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/183982/revisions) with other questions on other Stack exchange sites.