# Why did this edit get rejected as "deviates from original intent"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12806412/revisions) included a Django solution prior to Django version 1.6:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(
    'error', r"DateTimeField received a naive datetime",
    RuntimeWarning, r'django\.db\.models\.fields')
```

I suggested to edit this to make it work with Django > 1.6:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(
        'error', r"DateTimeField .* received a naive datetime",
        RuntimeWarning, r'django\.db\.models\.fields')
```

and included a comment to this effect. The edit was rejected on grounds of "deviating form the original intent". Needless to say, the OP made the *very same* [change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12806412/890242) just a couple of weeks later.

Why should I invest time in suggesting useful edits if they get rejected, with all due respect, by people who quite obviously don't understand the subject matter?

Is there an appeal system to rejected edits?

*Edit: feature request*

Following up on below comments, I'd like to suggest that the review rights get revised.

Instead of allowing reviews by reputation only OPs, previous editors and authors of accepted or positively voted answers on the same question as the edit-suggested entry get first-reviewer rights. If the review doesn't get voted on in some fixed time, the review rights could be extended to people who have a demonstrated knowledge of the topic, e.g. by matching up tags and previous comments.

That is the final vote on whether a suggested edit gets accepted or rejected should be by those who are actively involved in a thread, rather than just about anyone. This way edits actually get *peer* reviewed.

Comment: edits in code are frowned upon, they are easier accepted on questions as long as they don't  fix the problem of the OP. On answers code edits are better left to the original OP by leaving a comment.

Comment: @rene IMHO that's just broken. So I have to tell the OP "hey, this is not working anymore, please fix it (I'd love to show you, but edits in code get rejected anyway, so I'll leave it up to you to invest the same amount of time that I just did, have fun!)? Quite frankly, that just shows how broken SO's review system is.

Comment: It's a slippery slope because that might just have been a bad edit by someone who doesn't know what he's doing. Ideally edits to code should be reviewed by people who are well versed in that language but that comes with many problems of its own. The decision to forbid it altogether is the lesser of two evils.

Comment: The system is fine, the users are at fault here. if they would skip things they can't judge things would go smoother. Until every user realized that we have to accept that our good intentions sometimes gets blocked by robo-reviewers.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel well, isn't the peer review system supposed to guarantee that edits make sense? If it can't guarantee that but rather favors rejection over acceptance for any "complicated" edits (which this one clearly isn't, it was well explained by the additional comment), it is just a bureaucratic system, and as such doesn't deserve the label '_peer_ review'.

Comment: downvoters, please explain. That's another bad habit on SO and here.

Comment: I quit the review queues a year ago for a reason: it's filled with people that simply approve everything. Placing faith in the reviewers is a gamble which often does not work out.

Comment: @miraculixx you have tagged this post as feature request. Downvotes on those kind of posts indicate *no, thank you don't implement that FR* and maybe someone lost his keys...

Comment: Tip: Don't tack a feature-request on the end. Make it its own clean post, maybe linking this as motivation.

Comment: Obligatory read [Is it OK to edit the question to change the author's intention](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836)

Comment: The odds that you'll get a reviewer that knows anything about django versions is just too low.  They'll choose the safe way.

Comment: @HansPassant safe for whom? that's why I'm proposing to change the way reviews work.

Comment: Safe for future readers of course.  I'll propose you earn another 1800 rep so you don't have to be reviewed anymore and can make these kind of edits at your heart's content.

Comment: @HansPassant Well that's my whole point, the reviewers' decision was _not_ safe for future readers... On your suggestion to earn more rep, I'll take that with a grain of salt - however, if I was only looking out for myself I wouldn't be on SO in the first place ;-)

Comment: Why not just add an answer with the updated code? Link back to the original answer to make clear where the original code came from, and add text around what you changed to make it work with the new version. If you feel bad about getting rep for someone else's answer, make it a community wiki. That seems like an even safer bet than editing other people's answers...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan then why offer edits on SO in the first place? Let's just all add new answers for every typo that we see... The answer was perfect except it was outdated, which is one of the [very reasons](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290024/890242) for edits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right, and the reviewers were wrong.

There's this notion on Stack Overflow that editing code is a taboo. That's wrong.

As long as the *intent* wasn't changed, code editing is just fine. Don't let it discourage you.

Comment: Though it is risky, as edits to code are harder to judge. Twice that in questions. And naturally, it must still work for the original version...

Comment: `it must still work for the original version...` well, it does.

Comment: @Deduplicator if it's too hard to judge, don't judge. It's that simple. Rejecting mindlessly because "o noez it haz codez in ze edit!" is not a good move.

Comment: [Is it OK to edit the question to change the author's intention](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836)

Comment: @Braiam I didn't edit the question.

Comment: @miraculixx is the same guidance for all edits.

Comment: @Braiam my edit didn't change the author's intention either.

Comment: @miraculixx if you read the answer, it says that "intention" doesn't matter: *Crucially, there's nothing about **intent** there; you won't always know what the intentions of the author were until he clarifies by commenting, accepting or reverting your edit.*

Comment: @SecondRikudo: Yes. Which doesn't change that many judge even if they aren't qualified, though that's more often the accept-bots.

Answer (score 5):

Lets see what the help center says:

> #### When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so. The original author of a question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of reputation level.
>
> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - **To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages**
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

So, if your edit makes it works with later versions of whatever you are doing, please do so. If you see a suggested edit that does, please approve it. If you are unsure, skip it.