# Why was my code-edit rejected even when it is simple and clear?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I removed an unnecessary field from a class in an answer and my edit was rejected.

Was the edit too simple to accept?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7912443

Comment: Thanks for everyone for participating in the discussion surrounding this question. I am convinced that my edit is very neutral and my edit is barely a "code" change. It's really just a removal of some artifact that remained as part of a copy/paste thing. Of course since it is code, and code can be arbitrarily sophisticated, we have room to consider that removing an unnecessary field is very extremely dangerous with an infinite butterfly effect.

Comment: I also understand that as the question owner I get to acccept whichever answer I want, which is kind of imposing my opinion which is not "open mindedness" but still I understand the other side that says: "don't change any code" but if I can't contribute code edits this removes a very important mode of interaction from this site's overall experience!

Comment: Don't take it personal. Some of the *people* who reject the edit may have some problems. Just look at *andrewsi*. Approved 2'131 posts, rejected almost 22'000 posts! He must be a almighty god but we are too stupid to realize it!

Comment: Well, I could have suggested the code edit as part of an answer to the question. What I learned is that I should leave the code in the question intact because it might indicate something the OP was inquiring about. Also, my edit indeed did not provide a great improvement... So more than a year later: I'm ok with the rejection now... :')

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Your edit was incorrectly rejected; you removed a completely useless line of code - that's good, makes everything clearer and harms no one.

This is a collaboratively edited site, and whilst editing the code in questions can be dangerous doing so in answers is perfectly acceptable as long as you've tested it first and know what you're talking about.

See also: [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/458741)

Comment: +1 Exactly, "Don't edit code" is not a thoughtless dogmatic rule. I removed a field in an answer that clearly intends to not use that field. That field was not even involved in any other semantics.

Comment: I think the moderators just wanted to get on some kind of moderation bandwagon and do what everyone will do without really thinking about it

Answer (score 12):

That edit might have been considered as a *radical change*.

It's not a good idea to fix code in questions by editing, just fix formatting.

If these fixes aren't part of the problem asked (such that you can post those fixes as an answer) notify the OP in a comment about it.

Comment: But I fixed code in an answer, not a question. The answer inherited an unnecessary piece of code (a field, which I tried to remove)...

Comment: @Mzn It doesn't matter if it was in an answer, anyway let the OP do so. Just make a comment notification about your doubts.

Comment: A exception to that is removing irrelevant code and creating a MCVE.

Comment: @Braiam, exactly: I removed an unnecessary field that was there as a typographical error of copying from the question! That fieldd was obviously there because it was in the question.

Pie alpha: I think it matters. The question comes with code that represents the problem the user is in. If the code in the question is correct then there is no problem and no question! But I improved on code in an answer that inherited some code artifacts from the question.

Maybe it's a bad idea to edit because we don't want to enter a rabbit hole of discussion about what constitutes a valid code change or not

Comment: @Mzn you may want to hold your grounds based on this [Is it OK to edit the question to change the author's intention](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that interesting answer mentioning a nice encounter with Richard Feynman. I don't think it applies to me because I didn't not change the visible intent of anything or anyone. Did I change anyone's or anything's intentions?

Answer (score 6):

You should edit things like adding/removing line breaks, indentation, spelling and grammar.

Fixing method's names (even if they contain a typo), or trying to rename variables or code logic is not a good idea and probably won't be approved.

Answer (score -2):

You can see why people [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7912443) your suggestion.

You removed some code form the answer. Normally I reject suggestion if people change codes from answer or question may be the edit is right. I fell the right way to ask the OP whether that line is right or not.OP may change it or give reply why that line is there.

What I approve:

- Formatted code:If the formatted code looks better than original
- Spelling mistakes.
- Grammatical errors.(But my grammar also not good so sometimes I skip it)
- Appropriate tags.
- Improved the question/answer keeping author intend.
- Removed 'Thank you' or 'welcome' or 'any greeting text'

What I reject:

- Changed code.(Changing or removing code may be that right)
- Changing text Case sensitive.(Php to PHP,php to PHP, i to I unless too much change)
- Adding extra code.(That code may be helpful but I think it is better to write new answer instead of edit the answer)
- And other rejection reason is common like spam,adding in-appropriate tags,format code that are already enough formatted etc.

Comment: I looked at the reasons, and I think only this one applies to me:
This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Removing the field does not really enhance readability, but maybe someone might be confused as to why it is there!

So I understand how this "no code change rule" works, but why in even this simple case?