# Should I reject or approve this code edit suggestion?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, code

I've already read main question on this topic, [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292122/why-was-my-code-edit-rejected-even-when-it-is-simple-and-clear) one too, still I'm not sure what to do with this edit suggestion:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29672048

This edit does not break any logic and the variable name `duration` better fit its purpose than `speed` one. It is also slightly simplifies the code. On the other side, it looks like any code edit except those that correct programming language errors (like [this](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/409097) one) is generally undesirable. It seems to me that it is better to reject this edit suggestion, but I want to ask for the advice from community.

Comment: It has been rejected (2 votes to 1) already.

Comment: well, the thing is, the site is looking for the community to act on these. You, being in the community, are in a position to make a decision here. Does the edit alter the author's meaning? does it make the post worse? does it improve the post *at all*? in this case it literally changes the result. I'd argue that changes the author's meaning. but if you felt it wasn't *enough* of a change to warrant a rejection, that's your opinion to express.

Comment: I would reject it, the edit doesn't seem to improve the post in any significant way. One less line of code is nice, but, it's a line that isn't contributing to the result in a meaningful way. No real harm in it being there.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, I think I'm understand basic principles. Suggested edit seemed reasonable to me, but I was going to reject it too.

Comment: Don't edit code other than whitespace that you know is meaningless because you (think you) know the language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reject it, as it is an attempt to answer.

If the user thinks that the answer is wrong, he can comment and/or post his own answer

Comment: I think if I were him I'd rather make a gist with alternative code and write a comment with the link to the gist under the answer.