# Answers section shows votes of the question in new activity page

Tags: bug, activity-tab

Now it shows the votes of the Questioner and not my own.

The top one should be -34

[image]

Comment: Note that bug reports and feature requests for the new Activity page (not Profile, by the way) are currently being aggregated here: [New responsive Activity page](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/289905).

Comment: thx, but i am not member of the SE Page and don't look there

Comment: Just got [added there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372716/347191)

Comment: Interestingly, me looking nbk's page shows the correct information on their answer's score, but looking at my own answer list still shows the question score.

Comment: @computercarguy Try [@nbk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/5193536)'s [`Activity` tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5193536/nbk?tab=topactivity).  The [topmost "answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411062) ("`Should I reject or approve this code edit suggestion? [duplicate]`") actually displays the [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411062), yet they look identical by pure coincidence: the vote counts *happen* to be identical; and the question has *an* accepted answer which *happens* to be the user's, so they are both green.

Comment: the meta site from which posted shpw teh same error like stackoverfow  as does dba, it is a general problem,

Comment: @computercarguy *However*, if you look a bit further down the list of "answers", you'll find [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410911) ("`Fresh Question Shielding -- now with no effect on users with less than 5 answers`"). It is green with a score of `-11`; yet [@nbk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/5193536)'s [actual answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410916) is unaccepted with a score of `+2`.

Comment: @Greg, yes, I see that the two lists of answers have different scores and accepted marks for the same answers on the two different pages. That's... weird. I'd think they have the same query for both pages. Sounds like a code smell as well as a bug. Nice catch.

Comment: @computercarguy It's certainly an odd situation. I ended up scrutinizing half a dozen profiles, for fear that I was conflating **(1)** "it so happens that a counterexample hasn't *yet* been *found*" with **(2)** "it so happens that a counterexample *does* not yet *exist*"; or **(2)** with **(3)** "it is logically proven that a counterexample *cannot ever* exist".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because itis now soved.