# How can I revive a long-dead question?

Tags: support, questions

Let's say I have a question I want to ask on Stack Overflow.

But a quick Google search tells me that question has already been asked before (let's say around one year back). But **no answers are available** because maybe one year back there was no solution, but **now there could be very easy solutions**.

So, I obviously should not ask a new question (it would be marked duplicate anyway). But the old question won't be seen by the most (almost all) of the members who can potentially answer this question or who would be interested to answer this question.  (because it's old).

Now, how can I revive that question so that it appears in people's newest queue?

Adding bounty is one way, but what if I don't have add bounty privileges?

Comment: What makes you think you don't have bounty privileges? Or are you asking for the benefit of others?

Comment: I do have bounty privilege. I asked for others. And even I faced this issue when I didn't have sometime back.

Comment: Its a good question. Many people today are "stuck" in the 2000-3000 internet point situation where you might want to post a bounty on something, but doing so will likely make you lose site privileges so you don't really want to do that. You can stick to 50/100 point bounties but I don't think that will motivate many people.

Comment: edit the question?

Comment: @Jongware There are often specifics inbetween questions. Also we are discouraged to change (or even add details to) existing questions to suit our own needs. So if he has anything at all to add to the (unknown) existing question, he should post it as his own.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier, I wish I could bring so much attention to a technical question as this, but unfortunately I don't have any such question right now.:(. I just asked this based on my past experience when I was still very new to SO.

Comment: @Code I see. This is hypothetical. Good that you ask these things and try to learn the ropes. Enjoy

Comment: Doesn't answering the question bump it?  It doesn't really matter if there wasn't an answer back then, all anyone cares about is if there's an answer now and in the future.

Comment: @Jongware Just [be careful](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288802/is-it-ok-to-edit-the-question-to-change-the-authors-intention) while editing the question.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
"But no answers are available"
```

Your question can not be marked as duplicate if no answers are available for the other question.

Definition of [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

> This question has been asked before and **already has an answer**. If
>   those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this
>   question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.

---

```
"Now, how can I revive that question so that it appears in people's
newest queue?"
```

Adding bounty is the right way to revive the question.

Another way is to share the question link with people who may answer over the social media (twitter for example). Questions on SO have a footer that says:

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email,
>   Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.

Comment: But reposting a similar question might be altogether more effective, given it _isn't_ a duplicate, and new questions get way more attention anyway.

Comment: I would say reposting the question and making sure it's well formatted. If it receives and answer, the old question can be marked as a duplicate of the new one.

Comment: Might I add: If a question is seen as duplicate, you may only choose from questions _with accepted answers_. Ones that are simply answered cannot be chosen for the "duplicate" flag

Comment: @HunterStevens You may only choose from questions with accepted _or_ upvoted answers.

Answer (score 46):

> So, I obviously cannot ask a new question (It would be marked duplicate anyway).

**Reverse the table**. Prepare a *new* question with all the additional research you've made in the interim (for you *did* do additional research), add openly a link to the previous question and explain that yours is *not* a duplicate since the old question had no answers, and yours also has more information.

Better still, research likely answers on SO and add links to *those* as well, very briefly explaining why they aren't really germane.

Add links to googled pages, test cases, a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), fiddles, whatever the old question was lacking. Format the text appealingly. In short, whip up a *better* question for the same topic.

That way, if you get an answer (and you're more likely to get it than your predecessor), it will be the *other* question that will be closed as a duplicate of *yours*.

**Update 1** ...but, if all you want/need to do is to "bump" an old question, with no significant modifications, then it's best if you just add a bounty to the existing question.

**Update 2** ...and if you *do* have some modifications to the question, but they're minor, then simply edit the existing question. If you **do** create a second question, to avoid the worst case scenario indicated by @cimmanon, try keeping track of the visits it gets - maybe set a Google Calendar alarm one month in the future - so that if the question turns out to be a 'tumbleweed', you can then delete it.

Comment: How is this better than editing/improving the old question?   Worst case scenario, the new question doesn't get an answer either, so now we have 2 identical questions, neither of which have answers.

Comment: In my experience, "old" questions, even if edited and improved, tend to attract less attention -- or effort. I myself must confess to often yield to the temptation of thinking something asked enough time ago as 'less interesting', 'less likely to be useful'. I know I'm not right, but I fear I'm not alone either.

Answer (score 20):

The first thing to do is to [edit the post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

Go and try to improve the question quality.
If you can't, you might add the following statement at the end of the post:

> **EDIT**
>
> Maybe 1 year ago there was no solution, but now there could be very easy solutions.

This will:

- Bump the question to the top of the homepage.
- Bump the question to the top of the <kbd>active</kbd> tab on the [questions list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions).

---

If the question is still ignored and:

- You do not have the *Set Bounties* privilege or you wanna save your reputation score.
- You can't share the link on the social networks.

Then ask your own.
It won't be closed as duplicate because the definition doesn't apply:

> This question has been asked before and **already has an answer**. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.

If you receive good answers, the old question can be marked as a duplicate of the new one.