# Why would this edit not be accepted?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I tried to edit an answer tonight for the first time since joining this site.

I was reading through the answer (older) but it was actually extremely helpful, except for that someone else had previously edited it and changed some names, which actually broke the code. The previous editor seemed to have the right idea, just didn't seem to finish what they started.

Here is the edit I proposed https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12950868

One of the most confusing things is why the previous edit would even be accepted, Because it only changed some function names, It literally broke the answer. What I was doing was fixing the delegate name and function names so that if someone came across that answer today (as I did), they could take the useful answer and put it directly into there project without confusion.

To be clear, I'm not complaining that they didn't accept my answer, but I am genuinely wondering why they didn't, so that in the future I won't have this issue.

Comment: There a attempt to change the current logic of the answer by adding the `if condition`. I think this is the main reason why this edit is not accepted..!!

Comment: The other edit was not reviewed since the person who made the edit has the edit privilege and doesn't need to get edits reviewed.

Comment: The author of the answer is still active (seen two days ago). Leave them a message instead of editing.

Comment: A lot of times I see comments clarifying problems with a random answer, good comments are usually have a higher votes so they stand out and improving the answer with more relevant/accurate details. So you should comment instead of edit the answer

Answer (score 4):

You attempted to change the meaning of the question in the sense that you changed the code, which then can have effects on answers, clarity and many other things.

Proposing edits that change the question's original content to a degree that it changes the meaning and will impact answers will get rejected because they create confusion and delay a question from being answered.

Here was a question from Meta about this issue: [Is it OK to edit the question to change the author's intention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288805/5647260). It clearly states, and I quote:

> To answer your main question: *"Is it OK to edit the question to change the author's intention?"*
>   **Absolutely not.**
>   *Completely* changing the intentions of the question is hardly ever a good idea.

Your edit changed the questions intention by editing the code, which can lead to problems assisting the asker. It can also change the question's overall question.

**In conclusion**

Your edit was rejected because it changed the code's logic and probably, to some degree, changed the question's question. I'm not a Swift type of person, but the rejection was a legitimate one, due to a changing of content that probably would've lead to lots of wasted time and headaches.

---

Although you did remove some language, you should flag or ask the OP to remove language in the question.

Comment: I'm not saying that this necessarily changes anything, but it was an *answer* that the OP edited.

Comment: @zondo sorry I didn't read the question right, but bottom line, changing a question or answers content in a way that can break the code, change the meaning, is never okay. The person previously editing must be dealt with, and we as a community can rollback the edits. Please flag it and get it rolled back, do not edit it.