# Why was this edit rejected for wildly different reasons?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I've just had the following edit rejected, and I'm totally confused as to why, especially given the rejection reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17124415

I don't see any reason for this being rejected in the first place, but I get that rejections happen... however what's really confusing me is the reason given, especially "promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive":

> - Parfait reviewed this 22 mins ago: **Reject**
>
>   This edit deviates from the
>   original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic
>   changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.
> - Justinas reviewed this 45 mins ago:  **Reject**
>
>   This edit defaces the post
>   in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately
>   destructive.
> - alexander.polomodov reviewed this 52 mins ago: **Approve**

Can someone help me understand why the edit got rejected at all, and how it fell under those very different rejection reasons? I'd like to make sure I'm editing appropriately and I am at a total loss about this one...

Comment: You should be removing tags from the title, not changing their case.  Also this is a *really* bad question, even after your edits.  Don't spend time polishing turds, edit questions that will be good questions by the time you're done with them.

Comment: I don't understand why someone chose the "vandalism" rejection reason.  I personally think the edit is ok.  It makes the question easier to judge.

Comment: The usual reason is that the reviewers don't have a good way to tell you how to do it better.  Nothing resembling "don't polish turds".  Do keep in mind that these edits are an enormous problem, all they really do is keep a question constantly activated.  Making it more likely to get a lot of views, make user complain about the poor question quality and end up in the Hot Network Questions list.  Few actually qualify.  SO users have learned that the worst thing they can do is ask the perfect question, it disappears quickly off the Interesting page of SO contributors.

Comment: You probably got the "changed intent" reason because you said the OP wanted the code to work with floats *instead* of integers and the original post doesn't specificy whether they only want it to work with floats. (I'm not saying I agree, it's just the only place it looks like you changed the question.)

Comment: The question had **two upvotes** guys! How could OP known that it was a bad question if the community likes it so much?!?

Comment: @BSMP that clearly falls in "clarify the meaning" that [Shog got so worked up before.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066)

Comment: @Braiam not anymore thanks to the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The edit is good, actually, and I don't think it should have been rejected at all.

[What Servy said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355546/why-was-this-edit-rejected-for-wildly-different-reasons#comment507111_355546) is true enough: you should have removed the tag prefix from the title, and you probably shouldn't be wasting time editing questions that are a lost cause. But in this case, the question has not yet been closed, so an edit is not harmful in any way, and those are really minor nitpicks, not reasons to reject a generally correct and useful edit.

I don't know what those two reviewers were thinking. A leading theory is they looked at all the red and green, turned off their brains, and voted as if you were changing too much.

Comment: The fact that a bad question hasn't yet been closed doesn't automatically mean it's a good idea to edit it.  There are lots of bad questions that haven't been closed [yet] that aren't worth editing.

Comment: "Not worth editing" isn't a reason to reject an edit, though. The only way you could justifiably reject an edit on this basis would be if approving it would put the question into the reopen review queue, and the edit wasn't significant enough for that.

Comment: Since you're a moderator, you can still approve it if you think that it should have been approved.

Comment: So you saying that we should welcome minor edits that require reviews that don't make posts good enough to stay around? Indeed it is acceptable edit *if it does not need to go through review* and take time of several people (presumably reviewers should look at changes and not just click "approve"). I understand that there is no "good edit, but please don't make such edits till you hit 2K" button - maybe we should create one?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, At least for the [edit in question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17124415), I wouldn't consider it minor. It does clean up much of the post. Yeah, a couple of things were missed/wrong, but it does substantially improve the question. I would say that it's at least a step above the edits I've reviewed which I considered "minor". While I agree the "wait until you're >2k rep" reason button you mention would be nice to have, I don't feel it applies in this case.

Comment: @Alexei There used to be a "too minor" rejection option, but it was removed. Pretty strong signal that you are no longer supposed to reject an edit on that basis. Moreover, even if there *were* a "too minor" reason, I don't think this would qualify, as it wasn't minor. It also didn't "bump" an old post, which is something that Hans hints at in his comment to the question. This was a fresh question, and the edit made it substantially better—even if not quite good enough.