# Shouldn't I have made this edit suggestion?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I made [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25296652) with the edit comment:

> Comment: link and quote relevant documentation as it helps explain why the provided examples work as described

Two reviewers rejected it with the reason:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

I do not understand this response as my intention was **not** to address the author of the post, my intention was to improve the value of the answer for future readers. My understanding is that this is the whole point of making edits, hence I ask this Meta Question **asking for guidance**, because clearly I am missing some point. Should I have posted a comment to ask the OP to update the answer with a link and quote? That seems weird to me.

I found some text in a comment to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355547/2799887):

> good edit, but please don't make such edits till you hit 2K

...which suggests that I might consider taking the reject as a hint not to spam the Review Queue. Might that have been the case here? Am I discouraged to try to add value in this way? Should I just wait for my 2K?

I also have seen many suggestions on Meta to reattempt such edit multiple times and not to assume anything based on a first set of rejects. To me that sounds even a worst abuse of the time of the reviewers. So should I just submit this edit again? Maybe with a different / more elaborate Edit Comment?

I can accept that reviewers might have jumped to some conclusion, but without any real information (e.g. a custom comment or an improvement suggestion), this all seems a big waste of every bodies time and demotivating at that. I do not alike to assume anything with regards to their reasons. Ideal would be to ask @jg-in-sd @niklaz about their reasons for rejecting. Is there a way to make them aware of this question?

I dislike these rejects because I do not understand them. They demotivate me from trying to contribute.

Comment: I'm not a Ruby developer, but looking at the edit my thoughts are that the code format changes (from 4 space indent to backticks) are just noise and not necessary.  Adding an extensive quote from documentation is unnecessary, particularly as the documentation can change then you answer can become misleading.  Adding a link to the official documentation (and not just an archive copy) for this standard language feature that seems like it should be common knowledge to Ruby developers would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you added some additional text along with the link and that results in an edit that does indeed look like a reply or comment. It's a fine line between editing and adding value (which can easily look like a reply).

Edit to correct mistakes and avoid the temptation to add commentary unless you go directly to the question itself and add a comment or answer. Don't get too frustrated with the process. It doesn't go 100% correctly right off the bat and there certainly IS a learning curve. Don't let rejected edits bother you and before you know it you'll be making them without having to have your edits approved.