# Disambiguate [serde]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The current tag wiki for [serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serde) is:

> Serde is a framework for serializing and deserializing Rust data structures efficiently and generically.

This definition came to me as expected. [Serde](//serde.rs) is indeed a library that I'm familiar with. However, it seems that many other questions with this tag are referring to [Hive's SerDe library](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SerDe) from the Hadoop project. They are not the same thing, and should be disambiguated.

[serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serde) with [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust): [currently 34 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serde%20rust?mode=all)

[serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serde) with [hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hive): [currently 59 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serde%20hive?mode=all)

[serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serde) with neither of [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) or [hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hive): [6 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serde%20not%20hive%20not%20rust?mode=all), which I believe all of them relate to Hive SerDe.

Although Hive SerDe has existed for a while longer, the tag was initially created for Serde [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383809/how-to-transform-fields-before-serialization) (Sep 8 '16). Not long after, the tag was misused (from this perspective) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443746/hive-sql-serde-how-to-not-quote-my-fields) (Sep 12 '16).

I would like to hear from you what we should do with the base [serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serde) tag. I am somewhat biased towards keeping the current definition, but we can certainly think of alternatives. in particular:

- Questions about Hive SerDe would fit in [hive-serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hive-serde)
- Questions about Rust's Serde would fit in [rust-serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-serde)

Comment: Neither [rust][serde] nor [hive][serde] require any disambiguation.  The [serde] tag is not nearly big enough to stand on its own so a primary tag is always required.  Giving the tag a case of the dashing disease just creates silly tautologies.

Comment: @HansPassant I disagree that we should currently treat [tag:serde] as a tag for general serialization/deserialization matters. In fact, the tag has so far been used for either one, and both are bound by name to recognizable libraries in their respective development ecosystems.

Comment: You are just repeating what I already said.  Yes, it needs a primary tag.  And is thus not ambiguous.  If a hapless SO user only used [serde] then just add the appropriate tag.

Comment: @HansPassant Since there is nowhere any *requirement* that questions have "primary tags", nor a clear categorization of what counts as "primary" versus "secondary" tags, much less any kind of software assistance for new users (who are not to be ignored merely because they're "hapless"!) to know that questions need a "primary" tag, I don't think it makes sense to assume that the situation is fine as is on that basis.

Comment: SO users are in general plenty smart enough to avoid tagging a question with only [hive-serge].  They know that nobody looks at it.  In the unusual case that somebody still runs into it anyway then you of course don't "ignore" it, you retag it.  Doh.  Creating tags that nobody wants to nor should use, what the heck is the point.

Comment: @HansPassant Would you like to answer the question? I don't think I fully understand your point.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serde) should remain focused on the Rust library of the same name and the other questions should be retagged as [hive-serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hive-serde).

1. The majority of questions about Hive SerDe already have [hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hive). If  [hive-serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hive-serde) is big enough that people would follow it, then [hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hive) can be removed from these questions and then only [hive-serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hive-serde) needs to be applied. This would give back a tag slot for something more useful. If [hive-serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hive-serde) isn't popular enough to have people watch it, then there's no harm in leaving both [hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hive) and [hive-serde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hive-serde).
2. Hive SerDe has existed since [at least 2011](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-serde/), but no one ever thought to create a tag for it. The Rust library is much newer but *comparatively* more active.
3. Squatter's rights — the tag was about the Rust library "first" ^_^

Comment: "*Combining these two tags into hive-serde gives back a tag slot for something more useful.*" While simultaneously ensuring that people who know Hive but not SerDe cannot find those questions, even though they might be able to answer them. I'm fine with having a `hive-serde` tag, but people should still use the `hive` tag.

Comment: @NicolBolas wat? "hive-serde" tagged questions still appear to those that where following hive, if it's merged or synonymized as this answer proposes. You could argue the other part (that it would be incorrect to tag a hive question with hive-serde), but the discoverability argument is simply off mark.

Comment: @Braiam: He wasn't suggesting that the tags be "merged or synonymized". Note that the post makes no statement about synonyms; Shepmaster says "combining". He's saying that, *on Hive SerDe questions*, the "hive" tag be replaced by "hive-serde".

Comment: @NicolBolas remember that most people don't understand the subtleties of tags, for me "Combining these two tags into hive-serde" means "Merge these two tags into hive-serde".

Comment: @Braiam: Shepmaster has 90k+ rep and has been on SO *longer than you*. I don't think it's unreasonable to assume that he knows how the site works. Plus, as you point out, it's fundamentally incorrect to tag a non-Hive SerDe question with "hive-serde". Given those two facts, I think it's perfectly reasonable to assume that he meant exactly and only what he said. If he meant to make them synonyms, he would have said that.

Comment: @NicolBolas I've seen 100k members that were on SO since the beginnings of time answering off topic/duplicated question, so I presume nothing.

Comment: This can very easily be settled by the answerer: Edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: @Braiam First "shenanigan"! :) Given that Shepmaster does have a regular presence on SO, I would preferably let him edit his own answer, using words of his own. I don't see how your edit makes this issue clearer.

Comment: @E_net4 I claim that he meant "merge" for "combine", which are synonyms. Now the author disagreed with that, yet his rollback does clarify either. One would expect a user with regular presence on SO to know that when there are two interpretations, the answer should be clarified. Again, I presume nothing.

Comment: @Braiam presume that it takes literal time to type things; give me more than zero seconds between the rollback and the subsequent edit.

Comment: I presume that you know that you don't even have to rollback to edit, right? I presume you know that, so I presume you simply didn't wanted to, which is actually accurate.

Comment: @Braiam You are missing the point. Whenever we conclude that something contains ambiguous wording, we should _let the author of the content disambiguate it_. Presuming nothing is a way to be on the safe side, sure. But then again, so is letting the author do the rephrasing rather than overriding that with a personal interpretation.

Comment: @E_net4 no, we should not! Shog already [settled that issue almost 3 years back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066): *NO it's not appropriate to change a question such that it no longer reflects what the asker needed help with - but in order to edit effectively without doing that, you must first understand the intent of the author! How? Communicate with the author! And guess what... **Editing is a form of communication!**"* I communicated with the author, by editing the post, he simply rolled it back instead of directly editing what he actually meant.

Comment: There was nothing inappropriate with Shepmaster's behavior here: reverting that edit before a proper clarification only makes intent more explicit.

Comment: Heh, surprisingly the poster and the answerer both have similar profile pictures.

Comment: @BhargavRao there’s a... thing... going on in [tag:rust] with Kirby avatars and mixing up names at the moment. Just a spot of fun.

Comment: Hey, be careful there ... just in case some one flags you all for impersonation, it happened on another site, two users changed their name on April 1st, but they were flagged. (I don't want to scare you guys, but just stating what happened on another site... I personally like the idea of having similar avatars in a tag, though, it seems fun :p)

Comment: @BhargavRao hopefully if that happens the mods can check in with us; we all hang out in the Rust SO chat and it is understood by us all...