# Should a suggested edit that fixes a mistake in an answer be rejected?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

My understanding is that edits which fix mistakes in answers are actually encouraged. If that's true, why was [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17576077) rejected?

I reviewed *and approved* that edit, but then I found out it had been rejected by one user. A few minutes later, it gets rejected by another user, so *obviously* the outcome is: the suggested edit is rejected.

Now, that question/answer was about Java. Well, I'm not a Java developer, but AFAICT, `.equals` **is** a method **and not** an operator. So *from my perspective*, it was a good edit.

Hmm, I'm starting to question myself now *especially that the second user to reject the edit has a score of 923 in [Java] which is his top tag **and** obviously has more experience than me with 24K total reputation*. So, am I missing something here?

Should such edits be rejected? And if so, what are the rules?

Comment: I think the correct thing to do is to leave a comment. It lets the author respond somewhere people can see (maybe you misunderstood and the original answer *is* correct). I'm generally pretty conservative about editing other peoples answers for non-trivial matters (stuff like spelling, punctuation, and formatting), and the big rule is not to add anything that the author wasn't thinking of.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh ["Editing is a form of communication!"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066). Why do you need to leave a comment when an edit can achieve the same result better.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Don't know about what should've been done but this *is* trivial, the author knows Java and this is an obvious typo.

Comment: I would have approved that. "deviates from the original intent" / "does not make the post even a little bit [...] more accurate" is clearly the wrong answer (method vs. operator is not a "as intended" sort of change and one is *factually wrong.*)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh My thoughts are that one should leave a comment when the proposed change a) *Clearly* deviates from the author's choice. b) Is believed to be better than what it replaces. c) Is minor enough to not require a new answer.

Comment: @Draco18s *"method vs. operator is not a 'as intended' sort of change"* Exactly what I thought before approving the suggested edit.

Comment: he simply added **improved answer** as summary. Remember `equals` is not a method in all languages. People without experience in those language may think that the original post meant equals operator. so they rejected the edit

Comment: This would be one of those rare cases where you actually need a bit of domain knowledge (Java) to be able to do the edit review. To someone without Java knowledge, the edit might seem too minor.

Comment: ^(Also) This would be one of those rare cases where you actually need a *descriptive edit summary* to be able to do the edit review. To someone without Java knowledge, the edit might seem too minor.

Comment: @Braiam, You leave a comment (potentially in addition to the edit), [because, by design, authors are *not notified* of all edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415/271271). Thus, editing is *not*, necessarily, a form of communication, due to the fact that the author may never find out the post has been edited. Unfortunately, what the threshold is for edit notifications is undisclosed.

Comment: @Makyen by design, they *are* notified of all suggested edits. This is a suggested edit. And even then, this edit is above all possible thresholds, so the author would be notified whoever did the edit.

Comment: @Braiam, While users may be notified of all suggested edits, as just an edit it's not "above all possible thresholds". E.g. some edits which didn't notify the OP: [1 (rev. 3)](//stackoverflow.com/posts/45204613/revisions), [2 (rev. 3)](//stackoverflow.com/posts/45697887/revisions), [3 (rev. 8)](//stackoverflow.com/posts/42484482/revisions), [4 (rev. 4)](//stackoverflow.com/posts/42380811/revisions). The thresholds are *unspecified*. Thus, there's no way for you to reasonably state "above all possible thresholds". The examples, especially #2, indicate edits larger than this aren't notified.

Comment: @Makyen all of them editing links, which we don't actually know what are the triggers.

Comment: @Braiam, Exactly, we don't know what the triggers are. Thus, there's no way for us to know if a specific edit triggers a notification, except by asking the OP if they were notified. Thus, editing, *by itself*, can not be considered communication, because it's not guaranteed to notify the OP. Note that while example #2 (above) also edited a link, it inserted 23 characters which were in no way associated with a link.

Comment: It's what happened also in a post of mine, someone made a (perfectly valid!) edit but polluted with personal considerations and it has been rejected. Fortunately who wrote the answer (me, in this case) is notified then he has a chance to take a look to the suggested edit (and act accordingly even if it has been rejected)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It was a good edit. So good, in fact, that it has now been approved.

(Well, one thing was not-so-good about it: the edit summary. This is often overlooked, but it's actually a pretty important component of a good edit, *especially* one that you seek to have approved by others. It's just like an entry in your source control system. If you're going to change other people's work, you need to have a good reason, but you also need to *document what that reason is*. In this case, "improved answer" was not really sufficient. I see poor quality edit comments quite often. They are usually not enough to reject an edit, unless they are just a complete lie, but we can all do better.)

The reviewers who rejected it acted in error. I'm not sure what they were thinking, but I can guess.

A leading theory is that at least one of them doesn't know the Java language and therefore couldn't tell whether the change introduced by the edit was correct. Instead of skipping or doing a little research, they chose to err on the side of rejection. While defensible in general, skipping would have been a better course of action. **When in doubt, skip!**

Another leading theory is that reviewers simply don't know what to look for or how to judge quality edits. This is kind of a systemic problem, and one that is extremely difficult to correct.

Maybe they thought it was too minor of an edit? That isn't really defensible here, though, since (A) fixing a potentially-confusing misuse of terminology is not minor, and (B) there was nothing else obviously wrong that was left unfixed.

**In general, you should be approving edits that make the post easier to read, more accurate, and/or easier to find.** That means you should be approving edits that fix formatting, improve clarity (*e.g.*, with spelling/grammar fixes, and/or with improvements to the title), add relevant tags, remove irrelevant tags, and fix minor semantic mistakes (such as this, or typos in code). Pretty obvious stuff, I think.

See: [Privileges: Edit Questions and Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Given the realities of suggested edits and the nature of community review, it's probably best to leave major surgery to users with full edit privileges. It's just too hard to get anything that makes major changes approved via the suggested edit review queue, even when it *does* respect the author's intent.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I totally agree. Moreover, my thinking is: If a suggested edit consists of only one change, **but** it's an important one, **and** there's nothing else to be fixed (typos, capitalization, etc), then we shouldn't discourage users by rejecting their edit. On the other hand, if the edit **does leave** more obvious mistakes, I either reject or skip if I'm not sure.

Comment: I also agree with that thinking, @Ahmed. Those were the "(A)" and "(B)" concerns that I mentioned.

Comment: @Ahmed:  I think Cody's justification of the edit on the basis of "more accurate" is iffy at best. The edit clearly failed according to the _"This edit deviates from the original intent of the post"_ rule. Furthermore, since Java doesn't allow operator overloading per se, it's not unreasonable to consider the `equals()` method an _"operator"_. In that view, the text of the post did not have any actual _mistake_ that needed fixing. Frankly, if I were the author of that post, knowing that technically `equals()` is a method but semantically an operator, I'd rollback your now-approved edit.

Comment: A rollback would always be the author's prerogative, but the edit certainly doesn't fail the on-face "deviates from the original intent" test unless you assume that the original intent of the author was to use the wrong terminology. With that kind of thinking, no edits would be possible. Maybe I *meant* to misspell of my words and abuse inline code formatting for emphasis. The "intent" test is meant to assess whether you've changed the entire meaning of the post in a way that would misrepresent the author's intent. This does not.

Comment: _"unless you assume that the original intent of the author was to use the wrong terminology"_ -- not at all. The word _"operator"_ is _not_ _"wrong terminology"_. It's perfectly appropriate in the context of Java. The `equals()` method can be both a method _and_ an operator, and it's not uncommon at all to describe methods (in any language) as something more specific than just a method, when they are in fact something more specific than just a method.

Comment: (All of this, of course, ignores the fact that the question should never have been answered in the first place, being obviously a duplicate of one or more answers already on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: @PeterDuniho I really don't understand why some people take edits personally. Edits are meant to *improve* or *clarify* **Not** to *criticize*! If I was the author of the answer, and I saw this edit, I'd be grateful, *not angry!*. Furthermore, about how the edit clarifies: consider a student learning Java, and is beginning to learn about methods and operators. Wouldn't be better *and less confusing* for him to find a method actually called 'method'?

Comment: @Ahmed:  _"I really don't understand why some people take edits personally"_ -- this isn't about taking it personally. It's about whether the edit corrects anything that needed to be corrected. I don't see anyone around who is actually _"angry"_ about your edit. As for your concern about the person new to Java, wouldn't you want that person to get on board with idiomatic expressions about the language, so that they understand that, lacking actual operator overloading in the language, many do in fact describe common operators expressed as methods as _operators_?

Comment: Well, I have to bow out here, because I don't know Java, but I would not call a method an operator in any of the many object-oriented languages that I *do* know, and I feel like doing so would be confusing to the average programmer, unless it were clearly explained why you were doing so. Java may not support operator overloading, but it certainly does have built-in operators.

Comment: @Cody: _"I would not call a method an operator in any of the many object-oriented languages that I do know"_ -- what other object-oriented languages do you know? Because, in C# and C++, operator overloads are implemented _as methods_. But we still call them _operators_. Granted, in those languages, the user can and does invoke them using an operator syntax, but they are still user-defined _methods_. But no one gets concerned about anyone getting confused about whether they are operators or methods there. Why would Java be different?

Comment: Bottom line (yes, this is my last word): it is at least _plausible_ that the authors _intent_ was in fact to write the word "operator", knowing full well the difference between an operator and a method. Edits should strive to _avoid_ deviating from the intent of the author, and this means being conservative about what that intent might be. A comment would have been _much_ more appropriate in this situation. One needs to _know_ something is a mistake before making such edits, and not just _feel_ or _have the option_ that it's a mistake.

Comment: This is a ridiculous argument, as I've already said. If taken to its logical conclusion, no edits would be possible because there is always a plausible reality where the author *meant* to write whatever they did. The rollback feature is the contingency plan. None of this has anything to do with a good-faith effort on the part of an editor or reviewer. I was going to respond to the semantic debate, but I ran out of room in this comment, so I deleted that. I also realized this isn't the place for an extended language semantics discussion. Sorry, another time maybe.

Comment: _"there is always a plausible reality where the author meant to write whatever they did"_ -- that's a complete straw man, and you ought to know better. That it is _clearly plausible_ in this case the author might well have meant what they wrote, does not logically lead to the conclusion that _any_ author might have. Furthermore, this is both about _intent_ and _correctness_. A _mistake_ written intentionally is still editable. The edit here does not correct something that is unequivocally a mistake. Please leave your straw men at the door.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You're totally wrong `equals` is a method. Nobody who really knows Java is going to consider it as an `operator`. Looking at the authors profile he clearly knows Java. It's in no way plausible to assume that his intent was to write `operator`. Define plausible in percentage and I will gladly give you the odds that the author didn't mean to use the word `operator`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yes, an overloaded operator is written *as a method* but that method has special keywords applied to it as well. Namely the `operator` keyword. And you don't invoke them using `()`, you use them *as operators.* Java string equality ***does not use `==`*** it uses `str.equals(...)`. THAT'S the difference and why the edit is correct.

Comment: This has been an informative read. That said: @AhmedAbdelhameed "*If I was the author of the answer, and I saw this edit, I'd be grateful, not angry!*" I'd be confused, not grateful. Without the context of this meta question, the only explanation I'd have for this (one-word) edit is the edit comment, which IMO should answer the question: "*How does this edit improve the answer?*" - To which "*improved answer*" is a worthless comment. I'm glad this post was linked on the answer-post for the answerer's benefit.

Comment: @OhBeWise, I totally agree that the user who made the edit should've explained the reason of the change. However, if the reviewer knows Java or is willing to do a quick search *like what I did*, he will probably agree with the edit (no, I'm not saying it was okay to add a broad edit comment). I was just confused *(and hence asked this question)* because at least one of the other reviewers seems to know Java, so I simply wanted to make sure that my judgment is correct. About the author of the answer, as they know Java, they probably don't need an explanation for this. The reviewers do though.