# Should I have heavily edited another user's closed post for language/grammar issues?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-edit

I came across this question yesterday: *[How to check if the last line in a text box has only one word?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48949654/5779732)*.

The OP could not explain the problem due to poor English language skills. I had a discussion with him in comments to understand what he was saying. I understood and that was also confirmed by the OP in comments.

While our communication was going on, the question was closed. I thought I should edit the question to make it clear so that it could be re-opened. But I decided to wait and allow the OP to edit it. Till this time, the edit was not made by the OP.

So I decided to edit the question and have done so. I am not with great English skills either (it is my third language); but I hope the question is more readable and clear to understand now.

The problem is that I have edited too much. IMHO, the changes were necessary; but the post does not belong to me. I am not sure if this is good practice.

Please suggest if my action of editing this specific post was correct?

Comment: Looks good to me. It is way more clear what gets asked and you did only change the text but not the code or the examples. In general, every edit that makes the question easier to read and understand without changing the original intent is welcome.

Comment: @BDL `s/intent/meaning/g` ["The relevant guidelines here - the ones spelled out on the full editing page - are simple:

        clarify meaning without changing it;
        always respect the original author.

Crucially, **there's nothing about intent there**; you won't always know what the intentions of the author were until he clarifies by commenting, accepting or reverting your edit."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066)

Comment: *The problem is that I have edited too much.* If you were under 2K rep I'd say that your edit summary should have mentioned that you had a discussion with the OP but you don't have to worry about reviewers getting nervous about how much you changed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your edit looks great to me.

It's probably just about on the edge of how broad a third-party's changes should be, but when reading the diff there's no question in my mind that you have maintained (even clarified) the author's intent while providing some valuable cleanup.

You've also provided a clear edit reason that doesn't make weird allusions to comprehension philosophies that have nothing whatsoever to do with grammar alterations.

Well done!

Comment: Another thing to consider is whether it is worth the time to edit something that is already closed.  In this case, you could have chosen not to, but being able to re-open the question served a useful purpose, and hey! I even learned some things about Text Boxes I didn't know before.