# Significant reformatting of a question

Tags: discussion, edits, formatting

I [reformatted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64106314/revisions) a part of a question to make it more readable. The difference is quite huge, it transforms inline code into blocks.

Is this kind of initiative discouraged, i.e. should we edit only "small" parts of formatting? I'm asking especially because since editing with enough reputation points are done without reviewing, it could be viewed as a somewhat authoritarian action.

Comment: I don't see any problem.  You have enough rep to no longer have your edits reviewed, 4 hours ago and answered is like a week ago.

Comment: As a matter of fact, larger edits are better to do. Smaller edits are actually discouraged. +1 for the edit.

Comment: Looking at the two versions side by side, you really didn't change that much. I'm not sure why you're concerned; it's effectively five newline characters and a few backticks.

Comment: The only time I wouldn't reformat is when the error IS the formatting, a misleading indentation after a conditional without braces in C or C++ for example, because that pretty much answers the question or hides what the problem was from potential answerers.

Comment: What you need to watch out for are edits to code blocks that replace an acceptable style of formatting with your preferred style. And never, ever, fix errors in code blocks.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363794/5779732

Comment: "The difference is quite huge..." That depends on how difference is calculated. Transformations of inline code to code blocks does look like more than it really is. However, one should be extra careful not to introduce additional errors in the process.

Comment: @Trilarion, I also used the output of GNU `tree` command to format a directory content.

Comment: That edit is not "huge"!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Making larger edits is actually encouraged. Trivial edits are discouraged, as they waste the time of reviewers, and barely change anything. If you reformatted the question completely to look better, then that's a good thing. You also have more than 2k, but even if you don't have full editing rights, it's still a good thing to make large edits.

Edits will never be viewed as "Authoritarian" because you are considered a user who has full editing rights. If others don't like your edit, they can ping you, and maybe roll the post back. But if you feel an edit is necessary, then by all means go ahead.

Plus, as stated at the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing),

> To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)

> If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

Both those points are correct. If the OP doesn't like your edit, they can roll it back and explain why they don't like it. If the OP doesn't want their post to be edited and rolls back all your edits, don't start a rollback war. Instead, act like the adults we are<sup>1</sup> and let it go. After all, they aren't going to get an answer, so just mod flag it if the author is vandalizing their post, and leave.

The first point is also important. Never change formatting if the formatting itself is the question. For instance, highlighting all instances of `var` or `python` are edits that are discouraged, because they aren't required and in some cases look ugly. So don't (ab)use formatting the wrong way.

<sub>1 - in theory, of course</sub>

Comment: *Edits will never be viewed as "Authoritarian"* - I think the OP was refering to the point of view of the user whose post was edited and I know from own experience that there are people out there who hate it if you edit their posts and even undo it, regardless of the improvements. Don't get me wrong, I also edit a lot to improve posts and fully support what the OP did, but some people don't like it.

Comment: @jps, indeed, I was speaking especially from the POV of the OP, but of course other POV could also be considered.

Comment: Yeah, as a counterpoint it can come off as authoritarian. It depends on what the edit entails. If it's mostly cleanup, then probably not. If it removes backstory that some may consider important framing for the question, the edit is likely to be more controversial and could appear heavy-handed.

Comment: @jps Yes, that is true. But the FAQ is clear, it clearly states that once you post your post, it is free to be edited by anyone.

Comment: @jps  I edited my post to include that, see it. Also see Dharman's answer.

Comment: @10Rep, so you don't mind if I just edtied the formatting of your answer?

Comment: @Amessihel I actually welcome that edit. I didn't know about the <sup> tag in HTML. But if I didn't like it, I would roll back and ping you, the editor explaining why. But I like your edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

We highly encourage edits and the more you improve the better, as long as you keep the original meaning of the post. As *10 Rep* said small edits are discouraged, you should fix everything that you can think of in the post.

If you think the OP might not understand your changes and you fear they might roll back then you should clearly and politely explain in the edit summary why you made these changes. If OP still rolls it back then it's their loss.

#### What can you change in an edit?

You can change pretty much anything as long as you do not change the original intent of the poster.

If this is the question then make sure that you didn't change the wording to ask for something else instead. Make sure that the code example is still an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the error message is posted as it was appearing on OP's screen. Many times this requires you to change a lot. On some occasions, I had to change the tag and remove 80-90% of the code from the question to salvage it. You should also pay attention to the title and tags, as they are helpful in finding the question. Tags should never be present in the title, and the title should clearly describe the topic.

If this is an answer, then it's best to leave the code as-is. However, if you see typos, unformatted code or some serious mistakes you can retouch the code. Make sure that the answer is understandable and that you do not put words in the mouth of the poster unless this is a Community Wiki post.

For both, try to fix grammar, spelling, markdown formatting, and remove all fluff ("hi", "Hope it helps", "thanks", "TIA", "can someone help me?").

#### What should you not do in an edit?

- Do not abuse formatting!
- Do not add more to the post than is necessary!
- Do not add your own improved solutions to the answer!
- Do not add meta-comments (comments about the post itself)!
- Do not change the code style!

**The goal is to improve the post as much as possible without turning it into a new one.**

Comment: Although I agree we could do without the fluff, I thought it became official policy to let that be, especially if that is the only edit you are making....

Comment: @Luuklag That depends. Do you have the full edit privileges? Then edit fluff out whenever you encounter it, but don't seek it out on purpose in old posts. If you can only make edit suggestions then your edits should be substantial, don't make an edit just to remove "Thanks".