# Is this edit absolutely trivial, should it be rolled back?

Tags: discussion, revision-history, rollbacks

Isn't it a trivial edit which could conflict with the author's intent?
[image]

Which is more invasive, the first or the second edit?

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50251411/revisions

Comment: how does it conflict with author's intent? It doesnt change what the author is trying to say as far as I can see

Comment: "Here we go" it's an expression with a meaning, the edit removes this expression and reduces it to just "take it". I was, maybe too grainy?

Comment: What is even the point of both the edit and rollback?

Comment: @rene yes, that is the post also about. It's pointless from the beginning.

Comment: But how does it harm? They have edit privileges so no queue is involved...

Comment: @SurajRao Not harm, just useless.

Comment: The first edit at least gets the capitalization right. Apart from that... it's an exercise in futility.

Comment: As far as your question goes.. its trivial, is **not** invasive and doesnt conflict with anyone's intent except maybe the editors involved.

Comment: I see. Probably instead of rollback I could have preserved the H in here. @S.L.Barth futility is a great way to say it.

Comment: I don't see the first edit as particularly useful, but seeing as it had already been done there's no reason to rollback

Comment: @NickA Yeap, I saw it as sligly "less" friendly. Probably just a matter of my interpretation.

Comment: If your argument is that trivial edits should be rolled back, then if you are correct that the original edit is trivial then the roll back is also by definition trivial, and thus should be counter-rolled back; I see an infinite loop emerging...

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes, this post aims also to *spotlight* the edit loop when *futile* edits are done on posts.

Comment: For what it's worth, rolling back pointless edits is more harmful than just leaving them be (it's an unnecessary question bump, and the editor may cause another bump if they decide to apply the edit again).

Comment: @Dukeling that's a really bad reason... Further rollback from the original editor is really a bad move, we should not act and take those as valid.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier The argument for leaving it be might not be particularly strong, but the argument for reverting it seems even weaker. At least while there's no direct negative consequences for having your edit reverted.

Answer (score 4):

*Here we go...*

As I am the editor, I thought I would shed light on my actions, my reasons for editing are twofold:

1. The answer is supposed to be directed at the OP, therefore in this context '*here we go...*' doesn't seem valid, rather, '*here you go*' makes more sense.
2. I, *personally*, sensed an undertone of condescension (as in '*here we go, so simple*') which I felt was unnecessary. My personal ethos being, if you are going to answer, answer properly. Whether this was the intent of the answerer, I do not know, but I thought it would be easier to edit the answer.

I tend to do these more "trivial" edits as I have reached the required reputation for it to not clog up the review queue.

Comment: ["The relevant guidelines here - the ones spelled out on the full editing page - are simple \[...\] Crucially, there's nothing about intent there; *you won't always know what the intentions of the author were until he clarifies* by commenting, accepting or reverting your edit"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066)

Comment: @Braiam I see, the key point being that one should always respect the authors intent and sure, I never knew the authors intent (as I mentioned in the post) but I didn't disrespect their intent either (do say if I did). I merely, reworded that which they were originally saying to make it more clear. I see a distinct difference in the two.

Comment: It's backwards, forget intetion, just respect the author and meaning. You aren't a telepath (and I find doing it trough the internet even more challenging) to fully understand the intention of an action, unless you are told. Focus on meaning instead.

Comment: @Braiam fair enough, your point seems to make sense.

Comment: @Chris_Rands never too late!

Comment: I agree with the edit (due to the incorrect capitalisation that you fixed), but I disagree with your reasons for making it.

Comment: I sense no condescending tone in here we go, and would furthermore point out that answers are also meant for every reader, not only the op. I would reject such an edit if it were in review. Or maybe remove the three dots, but the change from me to you is actually contrary to the "answers are for everyone" goal.

Comment: and actually... it's noise. the valid edit here would be to remove it altogether. rolling back to it again is... a strange idea.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is meant to be a high quality repository of Questions and Answers. Part of that is making posts grammatically correct and easily understandable.

There's already been a precedent for ["Too minor" edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site), where the community has decided that good edits should always be done no matter how minor, although it is generally preferred that people with enough rep to directly edit without the post going through the review queue do these simple edits because then it doesn't take up reviewers time to approve something everyone would agree is a good edit.

If there's more things to fix in a post, of course the editor should fix everything they can find wrong with the post. In the case of this answer, I don't think there was anything more to change about the post besides the capitalization, though the rephrasing of the statement "here we go..." to "Here you go" does sound a little better. The editor has posted an answer explaining why change the wording, and the reasons are completely valid.

Even if the editor hadn't justified the edit, there's a simple test that you can do to check if an edit should be rolled back. Ask yourself: "Does this edit change the meaning of the post? Does it edit distract from the author's intent? Does this edit otherwise deface the post?" If the answer to these three questions is no, then the edit probably doesn't need to be rolled back. Simply being a small, minor change isn't a reason in and of itself to roll back the edit.

Answer (score 0):

It is an absolutely trivial edit. The text itself is *noise*, it should have been removed, which would have put into light the need for the answer to link to documentation and explain why use that function.

In both cases, the rollbacks were a bit over the top, both the return to the op's formulation **and** Script47 here rolling back to their preferred version.