# How can I make this question better?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

First and foremost, I want to clarify that I am mostly interested in how to ask this question, so that I get the kind of answer I want. I have the feeling the compiler warning the question was about is not as innocent as a simple style preference. So I want to know how the original question was unclear, and how any of my edits could be perceived as changing the question.

I asked a question on the main site, and in every version of the question, the main question boiled down to

> What does "The corresponding then clause does not complete normally"
>   mean?

That wording is in every version of the question, is referencing an explicit compiler warning, and (I thought) is obviously a technical question. The question explicitly states this was a compiler warning output. A good answer, therefor, should have references to either documentation, or examples as to why this compiler warning exists.

I asked a couple more questions with the intent to reinforce the fact that I want a technical answer. Here is the full question statement...

> So in all, What does "The corresponding then clause does not complete
>   normally" mean? Does this affect code execution, or is it simply a
>   formatting preference? If this isn't just a cosmetic issue, then what
>   are the risk/side effects?

Apparently, there was ambiguity, and I got this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49945189/timeline), which started a small edit war as I tried to make the question more clear. Since that answer gave no support for it's 1 line technical argument, and then went on to talking about style, I feel it never really answered the question for any version of it (but was still related enough to qualify as an answer). The very last question, asking for possible non-style problems with this warning, very explicitly makes style arguments not an answer (I thought).

Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49944900/6893866), and its [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49944900/timeline).

So, what part of this question made it sound like anything other than a purely technical issue?

Comment: _"This is pointing out that one part of the `if/else` exits the function with a `return` and other other does not thus the `if/else` construct_ does not complete normally _since the method ends before executing all the possible code."_ This reads like the exact answer to your question to me. Yes, the answerer added _more_ information, in an attempt to make their answer _more useful_ to future users as well. If that line does _not_ answer your question... Then you really do have some clarifying to do, I just can't begin to say what.

Comment: Though I can't say I see how your edit "invalidated existing answers" because you just clarified that the alternate code still gives the error you're asking about, and you wanted to know why... Looks like an appropriate edit to me, regardless of my first comment.

Comment: @Kendra I updated the question with an example that a return statement in the else clause still gives the same warning. (That was rolled backed and locked) So, that is clearly not correct.

Comment: But that's not what that line is saying. It's saying that the warning is just telling you that, hey, you're exiting the function early from the if/else, so the statement does not go all the way through before executing that code. It's just warning you there's a shortcut. That's what that line of the answer says.

Comment: You were engaged in an edit war.  Not something that SO users or moderators ever put up with.  Moderators in fact get an automatic warning about it.  No real debate about it either, you are expected to stop editing.  If you don't then the question gets locked so you can't edit anymore.  If you routinely do this on multiple questions then you get banned.  "Don't do it" is the only appropriate advice, if another aspect comes up from the existing posts then just click the Ask Question button again.

Comment: To add to @HansPassant's comment: The other party is _just as guilty_, regarding the edit war. I'd argue "they started it", considering your edit was valid.

Comment: @Kendra I guess my real problem with that answer, is I don't feel it makes a solid case for the argument. If it was that simple, why does the compiler bother looking for it? It's not wrong, but it doesn't really sound right either. Like I said. The answer works, but I don't feel it is satisfactory of a complete answer.

Comment: If you don't like the answer then downvote it.  Wait for another one, put a bounty on the question if none arrives in two days.

Comment: @HansPassant: The problem was that the answerer decided the edit clarifying the question invalidated his answer, so he _forced_ the question back to the pre-edit state.

Comment: Typical problem with edit wars, *but he started it!* belongs in a kindergarten.  The moderator made the call, no reason to assume or that I see that it was a wrong one.  What it takes to end a war and why we need moderators.

Comment: @HansPassant At the very least, it would be nice if important, relevant facts from the later edits where preserved before locking the question from everyone though.

Comment: @HansPassant Also, I didn't down-vote because I felt the answer had merit. Not enough to accept it though. I then edited the question to try and help obtain a higher quality answer.

Comment: The proper place for relevant facts is in an answer.  SO is not a discussion forum, all you have to do as a questioner is pose the problem.  And in particular not posts facts post-facto designed to discredit an answer, that always produces a war.  You did, the first version was fine as-is.

Comment: @HansPassant In my opinion, the edited-in facts were _not_ designed to discredit any answer (and that's a pretty forceful accusation). They were helpful in clarifying the problem, providing more examples where Eclipse produced a warning.

Comment: @HansPassant I added examples of what does and doesn't trigger the warning. (Admittedly, because the original version of that answer gave a solution that also gave me the same compiler warning) I included it so that others will have an idea of how-to/not-how-to trigger the condition I was worried about. How does adding indisputable, testable, provable facts hurt or change the question?

Comment: Well, surely next time you'll consider adding them in the first draft of the question so this can't become a problem later.  Yay, everybody is ahead.

Comment: Because everyone knows what details need to be included before asking a question ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus It might've helped to @ the mod in [that comment of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944900/the-corresponding-then-clause-does-not-complete-normally#comment87679114_49945189).

Comment: @Dukeling: Whoops

Comment: How if statements work tells you that the code is functionally equivalent with the line inside or outside the else. If there's a bytecode difference, it's almost definitely not significant enough to care about.

Comment: @Dukeling I linked to a question where return + finally had weird side effects, like what happens to control when finally and an exception compete. The byte code IS different, but I don't know if it is significantly different. I'm worried it is, but don't know how to definitively prove there will be no repercussions to ignoring that warning. Not like I can add the byte code to the question now though. =P

Comment: @Kendra - you are not going to win this one, you are wasting your time explaining that they got an perfectly acceptable answer, it is not the answer they wanted no matter how clear, concise and correct. This meta question makes that much clear on top of my previous experience trying to help them. For the record, my answer, was trying to reconcile the original question with their completely redefined question that had nothing to do with original one. The history, merits this out, if you do not have the rep to see it let me know.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome: I'm sorry, but with a username like that, I can't tell if you're actually being serious, or if you're just trolling.

Comment: Well, that's one horrible compiler message for sure. Talk about writing a tool that is wasting everyone's time with false positives.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To me, this looks like a case of mistakes adding up:

1. The answerer (slighly) misinterpreted what you were asking,
2. So he decided to rollback your edit clarifying *your* question,
3. Then he decided he knew better than the OP of the question, and engaged in a rollback war.
4. A mod noticed the (possibly automated) rollback war flag, and decided you were changing the question too much.

Each of these 4 mistakes could've been prevented.
In my opinion, this is an excessive response to a *simple clarification* of a question.

The answerer shouldn't have rolled back your rollback. It's your question, **you know what you want to ask**. If that required clarification, it's a pity the answer is invalidated, but maybe the answer shouldn't have been written if the question was unclear.

The final rollback and ***lock*** on the question is quite excessive.

Imo, the mod should've "taken your side". The edit doesn't invalidate the answer.

---

<sub>I just noticed that most of these edits happened around the 23rd of April, while these mod actions were taken 9 hours ago (may 14th). To me, that looks like a relatively recent manual flag, instead of a automated "rollback war" flag.</sub>

Comment: Some comments where deleted, but apparently that answer got flagged and deleted, and according to a mod, he had to roll back the question to re-validate the answer. (in which case, if true, why didn't the mod do that?) I don't really know what happened other than the answer disappeared, the question reverted, and then the answer was un-deleted.

Comment: @Tezra: To me, it looks like a massive over-reaction to you clarifying your question. The answer was deleted and undeleted by the answerer _twice_.

Comment: So, in this case, what would be the appropriate way to save the question? Burn the old one and re-ask it with what I know now? Flag a moderator to unlock it? (burn and re-ask seems more appropriate since I don't want to bother the mods, and the old question has nothing really worth saving.)

Comment: Re-posting a question is generally frowned upon, and you can't delete locked posts. Ideally, this'd be unlocked, and the rollback rolled back.

Comment: Based on what's been discussed here, I've removed the lock and rolled the question back to what I think is the correct point suggested by everyone here.

Comment: no they completely **redefined** the question after they got multiple comments ( now deleted ) and answers to the original question that argued that they did not like the answers and comments telling them it was correct. so this answers conclusion is completely off base Read the edit history on the question, it is obvious even without the deleted comments.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome As I said, the key question was in every version of the edits. I think I might have made the question less clear with the supporting questions following that. If you don't mind, what do you think the pre and post edit questions where? What key point did I change?

Comment: @Tezra - *why do I get this warning and how to remove it* and *what does the compiler do with this code* are two **completely different questions**, the edit history shows this very clearly and we told you as much in the now deleted comments.

Answer (score -9):

#### First Version

> So in all, What does "The corresponding then clause does not complete
>   normally" mean? Does this affect code execution, or is it simply a
>   formatting preference? If this isn't just a cosmetic issue, than what
>   are the risk/side effects?

My answer was an answer to this question.

#### Second Edit

Was just spelling corrections.

Then it because about this.

#### Third Edit

> This is not a format issue, otherwise Eclipse would put this under the
>   Formatting options (like with how to handle {} usage). I want to know
>   **how does this affect the compiled code**?

Those are two completely different questions, if nothing else it should be a new question about compiler output because that has nothing to do with anything from the first version, which is what the existing answers were answers to.

#### Completely redefining the intent of a question after answers have been given, much less up voted is never acceptable.

The edits to the question which can be seen in the history completely redefines the original question, completely invalidating the existing answers. The redefined question was based on false assumptions that are being repeated here on meta that were already hashed out in the comments. Many now seem to be deleted and my own edited answer trying to address the redefined question as well as the original question.

#### Comments on this meta question:

> First and foremost, I want to clarify that I am mostly interested in how to ask this question, so that *I get the kind of answer I want*.

It is a misconception that the purpose of the site to *get the kind of answer you want*. Just because you do not like the answers or understand them does not not make them incorrect or not acceptable.

> I have the feeling the compiler warning the question was about is not as
>   innocent as a *simple style preference*.

It was explained by myself and others in the comments, now deleted, and my answer that this has **nothing** to do with **style preference** and everything to do with the **structure of the logic**.

> Where you put the opening `{` is style related, to use one or not is
>   **structure** related and it changes the logic of the program if it is left out.
>   Same with leaving off an `else` block off an `if` statement, it is **not** stylistic it is structural as it changes or potentially changes the logic depending on what follows.

Comment: How did the intent of the question change? I wrote it, so I can only see the question as I intended it. To understand your point of view, I need to know explicitly how the question changed. In your own words, what was the original question? What did I change it to? And what part of my question caused the question change?

Comment: The edits my first rollback explain themselves where you deleted almost the entirety of the original question and replaced it with something else, that is what the edit history is there for. I have already been through this when I tried to help the first time, not repeating what I repeated then in the many now deleted comments and waste  time on the answer to help you again here. Done.

Comment: _"where you deleted almost the entirety of the original question and replaced it with something else"_ Uh... The OP didn't do that. _All_ of their edits added to the question, slightly reworded things, but never "deleted almost the entirety of the original question" or replaced it. And several of us see nothing wrong with the updates the OP made. They added to their question to try to clarify what they were asking. Whether I feel your answer addressed what they asked or not, I completely disagree that they invalidated your answer with their update.

Comment: You misunderstanding a question and posting an answer based on that misunderstanding does not prevent the question author from clarifying their question such that readers are less likely to make that misunderstanding when reading it.  The original question was somewhat unclear and ambiguous in its wording.  It was clarified.  This is why you shouldn't post answers to unclear or ambiguous questions, sometimes you guess wrong.  You not understanding an unclear question is the inappropriate action, not the author clarifying it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say you *answering* an unclear question is the inappropriate action.  Misunderstanding a question is unfortunate, but not necessarily your own fault.

Comment: ["The relevant guidelines here - the ones spelled out on the full editing page - are simple:

        clarify meaning without changing it,
        always respect the original author.

Crucially, *there's nothing about **intent** there*; you won't always know what the *intentions of the author were until he clarifies by commenting, accepting or reverting your edit.*"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066)

Comment: I'm not sure if the world's gone mad, but to me it's clear they changed the question, it morphed as they were given information from your answer. It basically means you've spend a tonne of time editing your answer to suit the morphed question. I actually feel sorry for you here, as you really have copped it.

Comment: @Servy - The question was clear and answerable in its **first version which is what I posted an answer in response to**, then they changed it fundamentally many times afterwards because they did not like the answer that I and others gave ( some people in comments ) and unfortunately the comments have all been deleted or you would see that. I did not *misunderstand* the question, I answered the question, they changed the question completely from the very first version in every edit to be about something completely different on just about every edit, the edit history shows this very clearly.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome The original question stated that they were getting a warning in a given situation and asked for it to be explained.  It was rather ambiguous about what they actually wanted explained about that warning.  You had your own assumptions about what you thought they wanted explained about it.  Your assumptions were apparently wrong, as the author, upon realizing that readers were making incorrect assumptions about what they wanted explained about the warning, clarified the question to explain what about it they wanted explained.

Comment: That's not them changing the question into a different one, that's them clarifying an ambiguous (or even arguably too broad, depending on how you look at things) into what they were really trying to ask all along.  These clarifications make it clear your assumptions were no longer valid, yes, but that doesn't make them an inappropriate edit.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Then it because about this."*?

Comment: @YvetteColomb: That answer was based on an incorrect assumption of what the question was asking. That answer did result in the edits, indeed, because the OP realized the question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: *"The corresponding then clause does not complete normally" mean? Does this affect code execution, or is it simply a formatting preference? If this isn't just a cosmetic issue, than what are the risk/side effects?* - there is nothing *ambiguous*, *unclear* or *too broad* about it, nothing to *assume* either. Those are short clear sentences that have very clear and narrow answers, that I gave that have nothing to do about the question edits that made the question about compiler outputs. And no amount of gaslighting is going to make me think otherwise.