# Is it wrong to suggest to a commenter to edit my answer?

Tags: discussion, edits

I've given a very short and practical [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960792/error-in-assignment-statement-even-when-l-value-given-is-fine-in-ternary-operato/50960871#50960871) that fixes OP's problem, but it didn't include any theoretical explanation to why the problem occurred. Then one of the commenters provided that explanation in a comment for my answer, so I kindly invited him to edit my answer in order to improve it. For this I was confronted by **another member** stating that it's my job to incorporate improvements into my answer and that edits are meant for that.

Was I wrong to suggest an edit to another member?

---

## To alleviate some confusion:

For better or worse the original comment exchange was "moderated out" by means and persons unknown to me, shortly
after this meta-discussion started. This, however, impedes this discussion which I have never imagined would grow to this extent.

I don't remember the entire exchange verbatim and I'm not sure whether it would be right for me to quote deleted comments of another member. I will, however, provide my initial comment which was:

> @username, please feel free to improve my answer with this information.

### Why didn't I improve my own answer?

1. I felt that my answer is sufficient enough to solve OP's immediate problem.
2. I didn't have enough time to provide a more comprehensive answer.

### Why did I write a comment suggesting the edit?

1. I felt that it would improve my answer to the benefit of the OP.
2. I wanted to let commenter know that I won't be opposed to the edit **if** he would attempt one, because I myself often feel hesitant about editing someone else's answer or question.

Comment: Nobody can reasonably demand that you spend your free time on a task that is not a priority for you.  Works both ways of course.  Otherwise the basic reason that everybody can edit your post.

Comment: If the suggestion is good, my advice is, save them a possible "deviates too far from intent"  or "no improvement whatsoever (interpreted as too minor by some reviewers)" reject (e.g., while you're asleep and can't cast your binding accept vote) and just incorporate the suggestion into your answer when you have time. I try to avoid gambling on suggested edits unless it's a particularly big problem and/or the answerer isn't responsive / hasn't been seen in years.

Comment: Also, rollback wars. I too usually let the answerer decide whether they will update their post, and I prefer comments to my posts rather than unsolicited edits.

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable for the commenter to edit & give the reason that they are incorporating their comment at your request.

Comment: May be he was busy or just didn't want to look intrusive or wanted to have his comment voted because people will always read (and vote) top comments on the answer they deem helpful. Anyway no one was wrong.

Comment: You can edit your answer, and attribute the update to the commenter.

Comment: @Viney "people will always read [...] comments on the answer" [citation needed]

Comment: @jrh "save them a possible [...] reject" -- Should we really adapt our behaviour to bad reviews, though?

Comment: Why I don't see mentioned invitation to edit in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50960871/timeline) ?

Comment: @Sinatr Deleted comments (and all accompanying meta data) are not visible to non-diamond moderators

Comment: @TylerH, thanks.. was reading MonkeyZeus answer and wanted to check the facts.

Comment: @duplode ideally no. But I'd understand if a prospective editor would rather just leave a comment with suggestions instead of spending time wondering whether the edit was too minor / too major. E.g., I quit trying to fix syntax highlighting and code block indentation after a while because quite often at least one reviewer would reject it for some reason.

Answer (score 30):

Normally, it's left to you to update your answer with information. This policy helps ensure that others don't change your intent or the substantive part of your answer. There's a bit of a slippery slope where a lot of suggested edits will get declined because they are adding in unprompted details or information, using the reasons "this edit deviates from the author's intent" or "this was an attempt to reply".

However, the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) states under "When Should I Edit Posts":

> To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place

Given that, and considering you explicitly suggested the commenter incorporate the improvement (ostensibly with a bit more explanation...), there's nothing wrong with your suggestion, despite the fact that it's a bit of a roundabout method, and the person confronting you about it was mistaken, or perhaps just overeager (I haven't read their comment).

Comment: "don't change your intent" Intent is irrelevant. ["The relevant guidelines here - the ones spelled out on the full editing page - are simple: clarify meaning without changing it; always respect the original author. Crucially, **there's nothing about intent there**; you won't always know what the intentions of the author were until he clarifies by commenting, accepting or reverting your edit."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066) -- Shog9

Comment: @Braiam I disagree with Shog, you can often tell plainly what intent was, and saying "clarify meaning without changing the meaning" is just another way of saying "don't change the author's intent". If Shog really didn't want us to focus on intent then he would remove that verbiage from the Reject reason in the Suggested Edit review queue.

Comment: Well, he's basically rehashing the guidelines for editing, as written on the site. You are not disagreeing with Shog, you are disagreeing with the guidelines Stack Exchange put in place to govern editing on their site.

Comment: @Braiam Sorry, I'm still not buying it. None of that disagrees with what I said ('don't change the meaning' is just another way of saying 'don't change the intent') and Shog even says you should know the intent by communicating, but he says one way to do that is to edit the question (presumably then followed by waiting to see if the author rolls it back? Not a very effective way, just comment instead) which I don't really agree with. At any rate, this nitpicking discussion is not really relevant to the answer; the intent part is purely ancillary to provide extra context.

Comment: "None of that disagrees with what I said" of course it doesn't disagree, it's merely not even recognized as criteria. Read the guidelines, they are only 2: meaning and respect. That's the only criteria to take into account. Shog is rehashing that, because people keep bringing intent, when intent doesn't matter.

Comment: @Braiam No, saying it's not recognized *would* be disagreeing. In other words, I am saying that `meaning == intent`. They are practically direct synonyms.

Comment: I do not intent to continue this discussion after I explain the differences in meaning of both words. Meaning is not intent. Meaning is what information the symbol of communication transmits. The intent is the purpose of the action of transmitting the information. That's the concept used here, by Stack Exchange and by Shog. You can find the meaning of the words in a thesaurus, but not the intent of the person using it.

Comment: @Braiam And I'm talking about answers, which are made of words. What you intend to convey is what you mean to convey. What you intent to get across via words is what you mean to say. I could go on forever. Like I said, if intent really isn't the right word and Shog has a problem with people relying on the word so much, it is something he can fix on his own in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 20):

It would be perfectly reasonable for the commenter to accept your invitation and edit your answer. It's also perfectly reasonable for them to decline. If I were the commenter, I'd probably edit it if I had time to do so, and felt I could fit it into the style and structure of the existing answer, but other people might have different criteria for what they spend their time and effort on.

Still, ideally, you should try to edit it yourself. The one major exception I can think of would be if you don't understand the commenter's point well enough to explain it, but think it's an important addition.<sup>1</sup>

In that case, making it as clear as possible why you want the commenter to edit it, and why you can't do it yourself, should eliminate any worry that you might reject their edit, or that you're just being a lazy sod who wants them to do the work to get rep points for your account.<sup>2</sup> They may still decline, but there's nothing wrong with asking, or with trying to appeal to them in a way that makes it as likely as possible they'll go along with it.

---

<sub>1. If you think it's a *necessary* addition, and your answer isn't good enough to stand without the edit, you should probably just delete your answer and let someone else handle the question.</sub>

<sub>2. I don't think the latter is likely to be a problem… but if it is, you can always Community your answer, I suppose.</sub>

Comment: "'s also perfectly reasonable for them to decline" note, the one that launched the rebuke was another user, not the one that commented the explanation which was the recipient of the invitation to editing.

Answer (score 6):

No. We allow edits on any post for this very reason: to improve the content.

Ignore the rebuke, there's nothing forcing you to not allow improvements in your posts, but the opposite is actually true, the system informs you that if you don't feel comfortable with other people editing your posts to improve them "this may not be the site for you".

Crucially, informing others that while you have the practical knowledge to solve the problem on the question, but not to explain how or why it works, others can help you to fill the gap and make a better answer for the benefit of all.

Answer (score 2):

How you say something is just as important as what you say. Since I cannot see the original comments, consider these two variations:

> Thanks, feel free to add that explanation to my answer.

vs.

> Thank you for the clarification, would you be willing to edit my answer to incorporate that explanation? I am not sure if I can properly word it myself without messing it up.

Both are perfectly polite and valid, right? Sort of, one of them (the first one) gives insight into your earnestness and it screams:

> Thanks but I cannot be bothered to improve my answer so go ahead and improve it for me.

---

In general, I vehemently avoid editing other people's answers because quite frankly it's not my answer and the poster should take and apply beneficial constructive suggestions whenever possible or else their answer might be sub-par for future readers.

If you rely on a comment for future readers to understand your answer then please remember that comments are second class citizens and can be pruned relatively easily:

> Comments are second class citizens on the Stack Exchange network, not designed to hold information for all eternity. They may get cleaned up at any time. Generally, **truly important information should be incorporated into an answer anyway** (either by posting a new answer, if the information answers the question at least partially, or by editing an existing answer, if the information is a minor complement or clarification of that answer).

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/235923

Comment: Sometimes i have no interest in adding something to my answer and believe that it suffices as is, in these cases I'll leave a comment with the meaning: "I don't feel strongly either way, but if you want to add that in then i wont stop you." Realistically, we may have differing opinions on what is a "better" answer in different scenarios so dont go thinking that everyone needs to adapt to _your_ vision of a good answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant There are endless examples of situations in which you do not wish to change your own answer regardless of the constructiveness of the comment and I respect that but I did not want to start listing all scenarios in my answer. OP offers no insight into their reasoning for inviting someone else to edit their answer and since they did not provide the actual comment exchange then I can only guess that they thought the comment is worthy of being added to their answer.

Comment: _"the poster should take and apply constructive suggestions whenever possible or else their answer will be sub-par for future readers."_ not always true. Many times constructive suggestions can be wrong, or unnecessary, etc. That's my point.

Comment: @TinyGiant ***should*** not "must"

Comment: Why **should** they? Why shouldn't  they make their own decisions based on what they think will be best in their answer? Ultimately if they feel that their answer is better without it then that **should** be within their purview. If someone else disagrees then it **should** be within their purview to post their own answer that meets their own view of what a good answer would be there.

Comment: @TinyGiant thanks, hopefully my recent edit alleviates the perceived absoluteness of my post.

Comment: ... Not at all.

Comment: Well then, your suggestions have been noted but I do not wish to alter my answer any further, thanks.

Comment: I think that the amount of edits and clarifications you had to make to your own answer is indicative that neither of the formulations you provided actually "screams" what you are suggesting, however, any formulation of anything really can be read into as having a negative tone by someone.