# Contesting a rejected edit on a question bumped by Community

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I'm trying to understand why my edit, [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20314755), was rejected.

To start, I disagree with both of the rejecters' reasons for rejecting the edit. The first reason given was

> "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.".

I do not necessarily disagree that I could have commented with the hopes that the OP of the answer in question would read the comment and update his or her answer accordingly if he or she agrees. I do, however, disagree with the assumption that my edit was intended to address the OP of the answer. My intent was only to improve the answer to account for an edge-case in the code.

I wholeheartedly disagree with the second reason given for the rejection:

> "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.".

In no way does my edit take away from the original intent of the post. My edit was designed to correct an edge case that could potentially prevent the code from working as intended.

I took a look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) post for clarification before posting this, but it looks like my edit falls in a gray area in terms of code editing.

Comment: You're changing code in a code answer... That does change the intent, as it changes the answer itself.  In the question you link here, where does, in 'editing code in answers' does it mention anything about edge cases being ok? It even says, in fixing typos and syntax, that you should comment or create another answer if your edit makes the code do something it didn't do before...

Comment: Ideally the edit reviewer can see that your edit provides a technically superior solution to the problem.  That ideal is impossible to reach, the odds that reviewers know anything about the tag subject are miniscule.  Only thing you can do is post a better answer.

Comment: @Patrice have you tested the code to say that it changes the result? The comment says "get the last used row", does the new one doesn't do the same?

Comment: @Braiam for empty columns or columns with over 1000000 rows, it behaves drastically different. To me at least, that makes it enough for it to be in a new answer, not as an edit. It is an edge case, but I feel it makes it different enough, yes.

Comment: @Patrice the comment says "get the last used row", not "get the last used row in the first million rows", but the last one. So, the original code didn't do what the author wanted it to do.

Comment: @Braiam that doesn't change, in my mind, what the correct action is here: if you think the answer is incorrect then downvote and post the correct answer.

Comment: @Patrice the answer wasn't incorrect, just not optimal: it failed in certain situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In no way does my edit take away from the original intent of the post.
>   My edit was designed to correct an edge case that could potentially
>   prevent the code from working as intended.

Whether your code change introduces a nice side effect or not, can you be **100%** certain it doesn't introduce a bug, or reduced efficiency, or different results, or requires a specific version, or... etc?

While there are guidelines for reviews and community moderating, not everything can be pre-determined with the complex scenarios we have, so with that and due to the nature that "community" is a collection of different opinions, there's going to be enough wiggle room in how we *actually* moderate to introduce **ambiguity**.

When factoring in complexity of a suggested change such as "code", as a reviewer that ambiguity can often mean there's no clear cut reason as to why to pick one over the other, and this is why such things are rejected by most reviewers. It's just too hard to factor in all the variables, or even know for certainty you have thought of them all.

Even if you know the code being changed 100% and you think your change has no potential to introduce different result(s), do you know really know there was no *specific* reason the author did it *the way* they did?

That is why we have to be very careful with what is allowed as an edit, especially a suggested edit as then the onus of the edit being legitimate is on the reviewer. And that's a big ask, because they might not know the original author's full intent *and* now not know the editor's intent either. That's too much ambiguity to know the best choice, so reject is the only fair action.

For the most part, editing, especially suggested edits, are to fix typos, grammar, spelling, layout, etc, and are not to correct incorrect code snippets. I know some will disagree with that, probably because they *want to* edit wrong code as it does (arguably) improve the answer and site and thus help others. However, the fact is **we cannot know why the author did it their way without asking them first, and if you have their attention for that then just suggest your change to them in a comment.**

**Answer authors don't own their content:**

Even if we say that as authors we don't "own" our answers and can be edited, which is the case in some ways, we should still honour intent with important specifics in the answer, such as code. **If you disagree with an answer's method, approach, or code used, then this is the exact point you should write your own answer, because it is a different answer.**

Your edit comment was:

> **Better way** to find the last row.

Isn't this totally ambiguous though? What if I said, I thought the other way was better because...?

With an edit on someone else's answer, you claim part of that answer but don't take any ownership and thus are negated from any blame or problems the change may bring. The answer is tied to the original answerer's name, not the editors. So you have to respect their approach to some degree. Of course, typos, formatting etc, are not such a problem, as improvements just adds quality to their answer.

Your edit comment also stated:

> The only caveat being that if column A is empty it will fail.

If your change is incorrect or worse in any way, then you may then bring *them* downvotes from *your* code, and this is not fair. Even just a small seemingly insignificant difference can result in getting a downvote or negative comment. or not getting an upvote they would otherwise have had with their answer.

If your changes bring about discussions in comments, you as the editor would have to be there to argue the case of *your* code, however unless you have already commented you're not going to be pinged, and so leave the original answerer to discuss *your* code possibly without what your intent was.

Reviewers should honour all of this too and factor it into their decision. And so if it could **possibly** change original intent, because they have no real way to know all the possible outcomes from that change.

Answer (score 9):

I will agree that the first rejection reason is incorrect. You do not appear to be addressing the author of the post.

However, the second rejection reason still stands.

Now, I don't know VBA, and I am in no way familiar with the question. To my untrained eyes however, the new code looks significantly different from the old. Therefore, one of two things must be true:

1. Your new code behaves differently from the old. Well, even if this is a *correction*, even if the original was broken... that's not for you to change. By changing this, you're violating the intent of the original, which isn't allowed.
2. Your new code behaves the same as the old, perhaps with better performance. If that's the case, your edit *still* deviates from the intent of the original. You've made a change that has some improvement, but the old code was valid. So you don't have the right to change it.

Either way, you have violated the intent of the OP.

Comment: "your edit still deviates from the intent of the original" [*The relevant guidelines here - the ones spelled out on the full editing page - are simple: clarify meaning without changing it; always respect the original author. Crucially, **there's nothing about intent there**; you won't always know what the intentions of the author were until he clarifies by commenting, accepting or reverting your edit.*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066) The intent of the answerer is to answer the question, if the new version still does that then the intent is kept.

Comment: @Braiam: No, the intent of the answerer is to answer the question *the way the answerer intended*. If the answerer intended to use that specific code, then that's their intent.

Comment: Yeah, by selecting the last row, which nobody has bothered to actually test if the new code still does. Therefore, keeping the same meaning.

Comment: @Braiam I can tell you that my edit does indeed find the last row used in column A, and will do so beyond the millionth row, whereas the original code will return the millionth row if there are data beyond that row.

Comment: @NicolBolas So essentially we shouldn't edit code even if the edit is objectively superior? To clear up my specific example, my code provides the same result without the edge-case of missing used rows over the millionth row, and makes the same assumptions about the state of the data (there is data in the column being searched, and that data is representative of the number and position of used rows). It would be better to instead leave the code that could break there and leave a comment or post my own answer?

Comment: @Taelsin: "*It would be better to instead leave the code that could break there and leave a comment or post my own answer?*" Everyone is entitled to their own wrong opinion. No matter how correct you may be, you don't have the right to change someone else's code in such a way without their consent. That's why we have more than one answer, rather than just have everybody editing their own. Typoes and such are one thing; if your code is "objectively superior," then it ought to be a separate answer.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for taking the time to explain that!

Comment: "Everyone is entitled to their own wrong opinion" is not a opinion, is an answer, a technical answer to a technical problem.

Comment: @Braiam: Everyone is entitled to their own wrong *answer* then. My point still stands: you don't have the right to change someone's code in this fashion. If you did, we wouldn't bother to give answers attribution at all.

Comment: "you don't have the right to change someone's code in this fashion" yes, we all do, it is in the freaking help center: All contributions are licensed under Creative Commons, **and this site is collaboratively edited**, like Wikipedia. If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!

Editing is important for **keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date**. If you are not comfortable with the idea of **your contributions being collaboratively edited by other** trusted users, this may **not be the site for you**.

Comment: @Taelsin "*I can tell you that my edit does indeed find the last row used in column A, and will do so beyond the millionth row, whereas the original code will return the millionth row if there are data beyond that row.*" in which case the answer is wrong, so and/or comment to tell them, downvote, write your own answer.