# Removing an inaccurate statement from a deleted user's answer

Tags: discussion

**Note**

This question was recently closed as a duplicate of [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code). Even though it has now be reopened, I still want to clarify why I believe this question isn't a duplicate of that and why it should remain open.

For a bit of context, this question presents three main things: (1) a concrete example of a suggested edit that was rejected, which led me to (2) a more general question about edits to answers by deleted users, and (3) another concrete (but hypothetical) example of a suggested edit to ask the community whether it would approve it.

Now, as far as I can tell, those who voted to close did so because they perceived that the first suggested edit I made was an edit to the code of that answer, partially because the statement I removed contained a piece of code (`df.sort_index()`) which, had that statement been true, would have been necessary; hence the duplicate of [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code).

First of all, I didn't change anything in the code, I just removed a (false) statement that accompanied it. Then, even if you think that that can be considered "an edit to the code" (which I partially agree with), there is no "do" or "don't" in the section "Editing code in Answers" that is relevant to this edit. Maybe the only one that is somewhat related (though still a bit of a stretch) is

> - [Don't] Make the code do something different than what the answer says it does

I definitely didn't do that; the code with or without the `df.sort_index()` does exactly the same, precisely due to the falsehood the statement I removed.

Then again, even if you still believe that the discussion regarding that suggested edit is completely resolved by [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code), this doesn't address in any way whatsoever parts (2) and (3) above.

Most of the commenters below have addressed (1), very few of them have addressed (2), and none have addressed (3). This question would benefit from a complete answer that dealt with, at the very least, the general question I posed. This is why I believe this question should remain open.

(By the way, the fact that the statement I attempted to remove was introduced by another suggested edit which was approved—and shouldn't have—, and not by the answer's OP, is wholly *incidental*, and not *instrumental*, to this question. The general question still stands, and so does the second example which no one has addressed.)

---

This is about [a suggested edit I made](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26821451) which was rejected. The edit consisted in removing a statement which is objectively false, and, to the best of my knowledge, has never been true.

(Here's evidence, for completeness:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['two', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]
df = pd.Series(np.random.rand(8), index=arrays).to_frame()

assert not df.index.is_lexsorted()
df.loc[(slice(None), "two"), :]
```

)

One of the rejection reasons was:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

This untrue: I removed a statement which is objectively false, so I did indeed "make the post even a little bit more accurate".

The second reason was:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

Notifying the original author of the issue through a comment wasn't an option here, since their user account has been deleted. Therefore I saw no harm in making a direct improvement to the accuracy of the post by making an edit myself. The way I see things, if the user account of the author no longer exists, that answer should be basically considered freely editable—as long as the general approach presented by the answer stays the same, of course, which I think is the case for this particular edit.

This leads me to a more general question. For answers authored by deleted users, should changes that objectively improve the answer while still maintaining the same fundamental approach, where that same change on an existing user's answer could be rejected, be allowed? If not, why not?

---

As another concrete example: I wanted to make a different improvement to that same answer, but since I suspected it might get rejected, I "tested the waters" first with this other edit (which I believe would have been easily approved), and [posted it as a comment instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463729/select-a-multiple-key-cross-section-from-a-dataframe/36243537#comment111716192_36243537). That comment basically shows an alternative, more readable way of doing exactly the same. If I suggested an edit where I *appended* that text to the answer (i.e. at the end of the post, without altering the original text), would you approve it?

---

The reasoning for rejecting such an edit seems to be that allowing any kind of content edit has the risk of opening the door to wrong edits (content-wise), which in turn lead to edit wars, and the like. If this is the case, there seems to be a discrepancy between the view of the community and the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit): currently, under "When should I make edits?", the following bullet points

> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks

suggest that *some* content editing is allowed.

Comment: Write your own answer. Downvote the other answer if you think it's wrong.

Comment: I guess the main thing with that edit is that tt does look like you're potentially removing information... curiously (and somewhat ironically) that statement wasn't in the original post by the OP. It got added in by an approved suggested edit... so, I've retroactively rejected that edit - so problem sorted in a way I guess...

Comment: I would say that if the user is no longer available, even more caution should be used in altering that user's posts. If they are available, they are capable of unilaterally rejecting edits if they don't agree with them. If they're not, their intent has no defense. And, for the most part, would-be editors have an easy course set out for them: add another answer, with the edits and appropriate attribution.

Comment: @RobertLongson That does make sense, but in the spirit of "SO is a repository of useful questions and answers", a direct edit to a highly-voted answer has a higher impact (for better) on the quality of the Q&A. Also, that addresses the question of inaccurate info, but what about making a useful addition? (See the second example, at the bottom of my question)

Comment: @JonClements That is ironical indeed :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sure, the author's intent has no defense, but then again what is inherently good about defending the exact intent and beliefs of the author? (As opposed to maintaining the general idea/approach, and improving upon it). SO should be a repository of useful and *accurate* information, and not some kind of forum for self-expression or a collection of technical essays. (I, for one, would gladly accept someone correcting an obvious mistake I made in an answer.)

Comment: your edit attempted to remove part that specified when proposed code is valid, which many reviewers (me included) would qualify as intervention into the code. Not to mention that formally edit suggestion contained removal of the (supplementary) code: `df.sort_index()`

Comment: As Jon points out and has rectified, the scenario is that OP's edit effectively reverts an [inaccurate edit that should never have been approved in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14528319). The new edit proposal _does_ match OP's intent because it removes information that the answerer never intended to be in the post.

Comment: However, had this inaccuracy been contained in the original answer rather than in a wrongly-approved edit, then the correction would conflict with intent, even if it fixes an obvious mistake, and should be rejected and left as a comment, downvote and/or other answer.

Comment: @ggorlen why mention so much intent? I've read the editing rules and only say about "meaning" nothing about "intent"

Comment: @Braiam Replace "intent" with "meaning" and you get the same result here. You're technically correct because you can never truly know intent, only what was actually written, but in my mind it winds up being indistinguishable as far as editing goes if you assume that what was intended to be written was actually what wound up in the post.

Comment: @ggorlen again, you need a direct quote from someone. The most accepted interpretation is from Shog, and he categorically stroke intent from the guidance. ["The relevant guidelines here - the ones spelled out on the full editing page - are simple: 1. clarify meaning without changing it; 2. always respect the original author. **Crucially, there's nothing about intent there**; you won't always know what the intentions of the author were until he clarifies by commenting, accepting or reverting your edit."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066)

Comment: Yes, you never know what intent was any time in life, you only have actions, and that's what you act on. If it later comes out that the OP's intent didn't match what they wrote, then they have the prerogative to correct that and state their actual intent. If OP made a glaring error in a post like "you can add 1 to 1 and get 4", then you have to assume that this was their intent, even if it's plain wrong or a "clear" typo.

Comment: @ggorlen So according to you we shouldn't edit "1 + 1 = 4" because that was indeed the intent of the author? That seems absurd to me. What's so important about conserving intent? The primary goal should be usefulness and accuracy. The "intent" of the author should come second. Who cares about intent if it doesn't provide accurate or useful information?! Again, SO isn't a place for self expression; it isn't a place where wannabe artists come to share their view of the world, which should be preserved as is to conserve the author's intent.

Comment: @Anakhand Yes, editing "1 + 1 = 4" no matter how obvious is against the [editing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). If it's incorrect or you disagree with their answer, downvote it, write an alternate answer or leave a comment. Don't change meaning. It's not a matter of self-expression, it's (counterintuitively) a matter of correctness. The problem is, it's almost never as cut and dry as my example scenario. [Jon Skeet said it best](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80513/when-is-it-appropriate-to-edit-another-users-answer/80514#comment196736_80514).

Comment: @Anakhand By the way, the post you edited to correct and are asking about in this meta thread proves my point. Very likely, the editor who made [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36243537/2) _thought_ they were 100% correct in their statement. I strongly doubt the misinformation was malicious sabotage. The edit was approved by multiple well-meaning users. This scenario shows why we reject these sort of edits in the first place. This situation isn't an edge case, either--if we open edits up to changing meaning, information correctness and consistency would degrade, not improve.

Comment: @ggorlen The editing guidelines do back what you're saying, but I'm not sure they should. By the same reasoning, the author *themselves* shouldn't be allowed to edit their own post: their edit could be wrong too. What differentiates the author from other users? (I realize this is kind of  a strawman.) Moreover, avoiding any edits that affect content at all leads to single conceptual answer being fragmented into multiple actual answers; see my [comment under Robert's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399999/#comment787731_400044). Can't there be a middle ground?

Comment: @ggorlen Also, this doesn't address the question of *adding* complementary content.

Comment: @Anakhand I wouldn't worry about fragmentation. The way the site is set up, there is a strong motivation for someone to come along and write a good, accurate, comprehensive answer, and these answers do rise to the top using _votes_, is the most useful form of community expression along with answers. In spite of what SO did recently by diluting votes using "thanks" emojis, _voting and answering works_. Shifting the discourse about correctness to editing instead of voting, answering and comments (as needed for clarification) harms quality control, creates edit wars and hides information.

Comment: @Anakhand Authors can edit their own post to fix accuracy, clarify or change their meaning. That's the point--you leave a comment and/or DV, they fix the post (or not). Why is this better than editing it yourself by force and without consent? Healthy discourse helps correctness and improves quality. Having said that, the content is a community resource to an extent and if the OP sabotages valuable content they've created, intentionally or unintentionally, I do believe there are grounds for reversal of such edits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219285/discussion-between-anakhand-and-ggorlen).

Answer (score 5):

- Write your own answer. Downvote the other answer if you think it's wrong.
- If you really want you can comment on the answer that part of it is inaccurate.

Useful answers get upvotes over time, your new answer should do so if you're patient. It really doesn't matter whether the user is deleted or not.

There are plenty of cases where someone's made a well intentioned change that's turned a valid answer into an invalid one so we tend to avoid doing anything [much beyond grammar and spelling changes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), or adding in information provided by the OP in comments.

In this particular case the erroneous statement was added in by someone other than the OP so we have an example right here. We've now rolled this back to the OPs original answer.

It's true that for a time we'll have multiple answers but high rep users can delete answers with < 0 score and we use the power of the voting crowds to allow them to do that. That way we generally involve subject matter experts in the process rather than edit reviewers who may know nothing about the technology of the post being edited.

And if not, it doesn't really matter, people aren't usually too distracted by additional answers.

Comment: While I agree that there can be some edits that invalidate an answer (we do have an example here), I don't think that the "Don't touch it! You might break it!" paranoia is the correct response. By encouraging to add a new answer whenever one wants to make an addition/modification, no matter how small that is, instead of having 3 good, well-edited answers that present a different approach each, you end up having maybe 10 unpolished answers that still present the same 3 approaches overall. Within each of those 3 approaches, each answer essentially "forks" another in a messy way...

Comment: ...which leads to conflicting information, and information being spread all over the place—especially when you consider that answers that deal with one approach will be interleaved with answers that deal with another approach, and that new "answers" (i.e. new edits, essentially) will start at the very bottom. This in turn leads to confusion and an overall poorer experience of a user reading that Q&A. Is this tradeoff in quality really worth the "let's avoid accidentally approving wrong edits by completely banning any substantial edits!" ? I don't think so.

Comment: High rep users can and do delete answers with < 0 score. That's often what happens to answers that aren't useful because there are more useful answers against the question. The power of crowds voting allows them to do that. So yes there's a process, it's just different from the one you keep espousing.

Comment: It is *rarely* the case that answers that provide essentially the same approach as another but with a minor modification reach a negative score. (In fact, according to the reasoning here, there's no reason they should.) So that mechanism isn't enough to deal with this—if it is even relevant at all. If it was indeed suficcient, we wouldn't have many questions with a barrage of highly similar answers—but we have plenty of those. Example: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13148429/6117426) question has 34 answers, all of which boil down to the same 3 or 4 approaches and have *positive* score.

Comment: How many of those answers have you voted on?

Comment: [And really only dead bodies hide on answers on the second page](https://digitalsynopsis.com/tools/google-serp-design/) :)

Comment: @RobertLongson Precisely. Three or four at most. Users will never go through each and every one of the answers and cast a vote (and if they do, it will most likely be an upvote). This *another* reason why the mechanism you mentioned (deleting answers with < 0 score) doesn't mitigate this problem at all. (But I do agree with your other points.)

Comment: @Anakhand The 34 answers with minor variants phenomenon is a problem that is dealt with by [protecting questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). If anything, it sounds like you're arguing for a higher rep threshold (or being a badge holder, for example) resulting in a more strict protection threshold to mitigate LQ answers on popular threads. The existing protection seems sufficient, though--34 answers for a thread with one million hits seems pretty clean to me. I don't see how shifting voting to edits achieves anything but stifle information and create chaos.

Comment: @Anakhand also, "It is rarely the case that answers that provide essentially the same approach as another but with a minor modification reach a negative score" doesn't necessarily matter for keeping the thread tidy and accurate which is the underlying concern. Currently, of the 4 deleted answers in the thread you linked, two have a positive score (one +5 and the other +1) and two answers have a negative score (both -1). One of the negative-scored answers was self-deleted and the other 3 were deleted by a mod or community votes. The mod explanation comments cited duplicate answer.

Comment: @Anakhand Even if edits that changed meaning were permitted and no matter how canonical and consolidated a single accepted and/or highly-upvoted community-approved answer became, I guarantee that low-rep users will still spam redundant, garbage, "this worked for me" answers. Voting, protection/rep thresholds, education of site standards and moderation are the only ways to combat that, not permitting editing to change intent.