# When reviewing edits, should I reject edits that introduce nontrivial "fixes"?

Tags: discussion, answers, suggested-edits

With reference to the following edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13411020

I skipped this review, because if it was me, I would not have edited this, since in my opinion it introduces a non-trivial "fix".

I would have instead left a comment for the person responsible for this answer, explaining the problem, suggesting the fix, and asking them to address it. *Maybe* if they hadn't acted on that comment and it seemed like the user was long gone I would have gone ahead to edit. *Maybe*.

I'm under the impression that edits are more to do with formatting and clarifications, or at most correction of minor typos that enable the code to compile (forgetting a semicolon or whatever). Am I correct in my understanding; should I have rejected this edit?

Comment: Skipping it was the right move. Putting aside the philosophical debate about whether these types of edits are recommended, as someone who is (according to your profile) not a Java developer, you would not be qualified to judge the veracity of such an edit. Me neither. But of our countless members, *someone* knows for sure whether or not this is a good edit.

Comment: that's a fair point, but it's clear to me this is not a trivial fix, so. the real question is should I have straight up rejected for that reason, or just skip.

Comment: Considering the question to that answer, I think it's not even relevant whether the give code runs correctly, since it's just an arbitrary example for code style. The only thing this edit does, is blowing up the example code and messing up the code indentation..

Comment: close vote that question, it is blatantly opinion based

Comment: apologies for my brainfart, I didn't mean to say "accept" I meant to say "reject"

Comment: @TinyGiant specifically it's "discussion" based. I'm trying to ascertain to what extent the "reject due to **attempt to reply**-style edits" clause applies to answer posts as well as question posts (where the case is clear).

Comment: As I said below, the edit is not an attempt to reply. It is not a comment being edited into a post. Whether the edit is correct or not is a different story. But in reality the question is the problem, it is specifically asking for opinions on the topic. Everything else is symptoms of the problem

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't understand where all this hostility is coming from. My question is very similar to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267845/edit-to-fix-incorrect-code-in-answer-rejected?rq=1 except from the reviewer's point of view. In the words of that post, should "introduction of code that changes functionality, even if the editor thinks it's correct" be rejected on that basis? I don't see why I'm being viewed as trolling. I want my reviewing process to be in line with the guidelines of the community, and in this particular case it's unclear and I'm asking for clarification.

Comment: I don't see any hostility here, nor is anyone accusing you of trolling.

Comment: @TinyGiant thank you for the clarification below. If you'd like to post that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Note that the user which suggested the edit does not have enough rep to comment.

Comment: Just to note: I dropped "automatically" from the title. Maybe I'm the only one, but when seeing the title in the list of questions my "robo reviewing" alarm went off and had to be quieted by the otherwise perfectly sensible body of your question :) If you don't agree, feel free to revert.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I had not even thought of that. well spotted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Skip

This is always the right answer if you are unsure about the validity of an edit

---

In the comments you've mentioned that you think this edit should be rejected as "an attempt to reply", this is wrong.

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

An edit that is an "attempt to reply" is one that introduces a comment into the question instead of being posted using the comment form below the post, or it could possibly be meant as a different answer to the question but posted as an edit to an existing answer instead.

---

If you examine the question that the answer being edited belongs to, you will see that the root problem in this case is that the question is specifically asking for opinions, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

The answers that the question has received and any subsequent edits to those answers are inconsequential because the question does not belong here in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, Giant. To help me ask better meta questions, how would you have rephrased this question to make it specific to the issue being clarified?

Comment: The question seems fine to me. This question is really multiple questions in one though, "What is the correct action in this case?", "What is 'an attempt to reply' edit?", and "Should we reject edits that fix code in answers?"

Answer (score 17):

Skip.

Hopefully there's someone out there who can gauge the validity of the edit. In some cases (though probably not this one), that might even include the original author of the post (who will be notified of the pending edit).

But in any case, if *you* aren't sure then *you* shouldn't be reviewing this edit... So, skip it and spend time on another one.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm being misunderstood. The validity of the code isn't in question, whether it's valid or not is irrelevant. There is no question about "accepting" at all in this case. The question is "this is not a formatting change, this introduces a clear nontrivial fix in the code". 

As a reviewer is it my duty to reject edits that introduce fixes because edits are not the place to do so, or am I being too stringent if I do so?

Comment: Why would you reject an edit if you *knew* it improved the answer?

Comment: if you hit the reject button, you get an option "**attempt to reply**: This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.".  i.e. the right form would be to discuss that such a nontrivial fix is needed. Not to just go ahead and edit the code in a nontrivial fashion to "fix" it.

Comment: So for example, if someone felt the library used in a code in an answer was suboptimal, and reimplemented a block of code by using functionality from another library, is that a legit use of the `edit` functionality?

Comment: when people edit *questions* to fix them, it's clearly bad form. But the above "attempt to reply" clause is a bit less clear when introducing fixes into "answers". That's what I want to ask people's opinion on.

Comment: It does make sense as an edit, and is npt an attempt to reply. That reason is for comments being edited into the post

Comment: You're coming up with hypothetical scenarios now, @tasos... You have a real edit in front of you, with a comment explaining why the editor thought it necessary; we need only confirm the validity of that.

Comment: TinyGiant what comments? I don't see any. Shog I appreciate what you're saying, but this is still not answering my actual question. Does the "attempt to reply" clause for rejection apply to answer posts as it does for question posts? (I agree with TinyGiant that if I'd seen comments below indicating that this has been discussed, then I would be less worried)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou On the review, do you see where it says "10 votes"? Look to the right of that, and you'll see the comment.

Comment: @Tasos Maybe I wasn't clear in what I said previously. An "attempt to reply" edit is an edit where someone is introducing a "comment" into the post itself, instead of posting a comment below the post. This edit is not an "attempt to reply", therefore it should not be rejected as such.

Comment: @TinyGiant ok, that makes sense. thank you for clarifying. 
(Laurel: "Ha. ha.". We're talking about comments to the post, not to the edit.)

Answer (score 6):

**It's fine to accept non-trivial fixes, if you're confident about them.**

But you weren't confident, so you did the right thing in skipping.

Comment: Yes of course. I had meant to ask the opposite, i.e. whether I should reject automatically because I was under the impression that code edits shouldn't introduce functionality or change the logic of the code.

Comment: sorry, I edited the post itself yesterday, but I just spotted the title still says accept ... I had a brainfart when I wrote accept, I never meant to do that :p

Comment: This meta post http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252806/when-should-i-edit-something-vs-comment-on-it-if-its-a-relatively-trivial-error suggests to me that it's rarely okay to accept non-trivial fixes if the fixer didn't attempt to comment first, regardless of how confident you are about them.